# Extract URLs from text in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this text:

```
$string = "this is my friend's website http://example.com I think it is coll";
```

How can I extract the link into another variable?

I know it should be by using regular expression especially `preg_match()` but I don't know how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract URL from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390556/extract-url-from-string)

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski how it will be duplicate the user asked on May 26 '09 at 14:13 but link mentioned by you asked on Dec 8 '10 at 17:44. May be the reverse may true.

Answer (score 51):

Probably the safest way is using code snippets from WordPress. Download the latest one (currently 3.1.1) and see wp-includes/formatting.php. There's a function named make_clickable which has plain text for param and returns  formatted string. You can grab codes for extracting URLs. It's pretty complex though.

This one line regex might be helpful.

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);
```

But this regex still can't remove some malformed URLs (ex. `http://google:ha.ckers.org` ).

See also:
[How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior)

Comment: I had a play around with the Wordpress formatting.php and using make_clickable is a nice idea but it ends up sucking in half of wordpress in dependencies.

Comment: Good one, to make sure the terminal part is not a weird character

Comment: This doesn't identify url without http, like google.com

Comment: This regex will match http://google:ha.ckers.org "@https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9\@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()\@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)@";  Dont remeber where i found it so can't give credit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366790/php-find-all-links-in-the-text worked better for me than this (context WordPress).

Comment: I tried using WP's wp_extract_urls function, but sometimes the URL query parameters of URLs in a string would have html entities, so had to use 
wp_extract_urls( html_entity_decode($text)
when processing the comment text entry. Otherwise, I'd lose some of the query parameters.

Answer (score 18):

I tried to do as Nobu said, using Wordpress, but to much dependencies to other WordPress functions I instead opted to use Nobu's regular expression for [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) and turned it into a function, using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback); a function which now replaces all links in a text with clickable links. It uses [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) so you'll need PHP 5.3 or you may rewrite the code to use an ordinary function instead.

```
<?php 

/**
 * Make clickable links from URLs in text.
 */

function make_clickable($text) {
    $regex = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) {
        return "<a href=\'{$matches[0]}\'>{$matches[0]}</a>";
    }, $text);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: I've updated your answer to use a anonymous function as a callback instead of using `create_function()`.

Answer (score 14):

URLs have a quite [complex definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax) — you must decide what you want to capture first. A simple example capturing anything starting with `http://` and `https://` could be:

```
preg_match_all('!https?://\S+!', $string, $matches);
$all_urls = $matches[0];
```

Note that this is very basic and could capture invalid URLs. I would recommend catching up on [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) and [PHP regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php) for more complex things.

Answer (score 11):

The code that worked for me (especially if you have several links in your `$string`):

```
$string = "this is my friend's website https://www.example.com I think it is cool, but this one is cooler https://www.stackoverflow.com :)";
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$urls = $matches[0];
// go over all links
foreach($urls as $url) 
{
    echo $url.'<br />';
}
```

Hope that helps others as well.

Comment: i've tested all answer, this is only one will remove the html tab

Answer (score 8):

If the text you extract the URLs from is user-submitted and you're going to display the result as links anywhere, you have to be very, VERY careful to avoid [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), most prominently "javascript:" protocol URLs, but also [malformed URLs](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) that might trick your regexp and/or the displaying browser into executing them as Javascript URLs. At the very least, you should accept only URLs that start with "http", "https" or "ftp".

There's also a  [blog entry](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/) by Jeff where he describes some other problems with extracting URLs.

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z]+:\/\/\S+/', $string, $matches);
```

This is an easy way that'd work for a lot of cases, not all. All the matches are put in $matches. Note that this do not cover links in anchor elements (<a href=""...), but that wasn't in your example either.

Comment: -1: you've just created an XSS vulnerability, since it would also extract javascript: URLs.

Comment: It's not stated what he'd use it for, hence I don't account for that. He just wanted to get URLs into variables.

Comment: @Michael: Finding javascript URLs is not yet a vulnerability; using them without any check is. Sometimes the presence and number of such URLs is useful information. I'd have chosen a different delimiter. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do like this..

```
<?php
$string = "this is my friend's website http://example.com I think it is coll";
echo explode(' ',strstr($string,'http://'))[0]; //"prints" http://example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all ("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+".
                "(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/",
                $var, &$matches);

$matches = $matches[1];
$list = array();

foreach($matches as $var)
{    
    print($var."<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this to find the link and revise the link (add the href link).

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://example.com";

if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

       echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);

} else {

       echo "No url in the text";

}
```

refer here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of edge cases with urls. Like url could contain brackets or not contain protocol etc. Thats why regex is not enough.

I created a PHP library that could deal with lots of edge cases: [Url highlight](https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight).

Example:

```php
<?php

use VStelmakh\UrlHighlight\UrlHighlight;

$urlHighlight = new UrlHighlight();
$urlHighlight->getUrls("this is my friend's website http://example.com I think it is coll");
// return: ['http://example.com']
```

For more details see [readme](https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight/blob/master/README.md). For covered url cases see [test](https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight/blob/master/tests/UrlHighlightTest.php#L11).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I use, can't remember where it came from but seems to do a pretty good job of finding links in the text. and making them links.

You can change the function to suit your needs. I just wanted to share this as I was looking around and remembered I had this in one of my helper libraries.

```
function make_links($str){

  $pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';

  return preg_replace_callback("#$pattern#i", function($matches) {
    $input = $matches[0];
    $url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";
    return '<a href="' . $url . '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">' . "$input</a>";
  }, $str);
}
```

Use:

```
$subject = 'this is a link http://google:ha.ckers.org maybe don't want to visit it?';
echo make_links($subject);
```

Output

```
this is a link <a href="http://google:ha.ckers.org" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">http://google:ha.ckers.org</a> maybe don't want to visit it?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/(href|src)[\s]?=[\s\"\']?+(.*?)[\s\"\']+.*?/', $webpage_content, $link_extracted);
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3g0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

This Regex works great for me and i have checked with all types of URL,

```
<?php
$string = "Thisregexfindurlhttp://www.rubular.com/r/bFHobduQ3n mixedwithstring";
preg_match_all('/(https?|ssh|ftp):\/\/[^\s"]+/', $string, $url);
$all_url = $url[0]; // Returns Array Of all Found URL's
$one_url = $url[0][0]; // Gives the First URL in Array of URL's
?>
```

Checked with lots of URL's can find here http://www.rubular.com/r/bFHobduQ3n

Answer (score 0):

```
public function find_links($post_content){
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $post_content, $urls)) {
        // make the urls hyper links,
        foreach($urls[0] as $url){
            $post_content = str_replace($url, '<a href="'.$url.'" rel="nofollow"> LINK </a>', $post_content);
        }
        //var_dump($post_content);die(); //uncomment to see result
        //return text with hyper links
        return $post_content;
    } else {
        // if no urls in the text just return the text
        return $post_content; 
    }
}
```