# How to mimic Stack Overflow Auto-Link Behavior

Tags: php, regex, string

With PHP how can I mimic the auto-link behavior of Stack Overflow (which BTW is awesomely cool)?

For instance, the following URL:

> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior

Is converted into this:

```
<a title="how to mimic stackoverflow auto link behavior" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior">stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/…</a>
```

I don't really care for the `title` attribute in this case.

---

And this:

> http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450

Is converted into this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450">pt.php.net/manual/en/…</a>
```

How can I make a similar function in PHP?

**PS: Check my comments on this question for some more examples and behaviors.**

Comment: So what you are really asking is how to trim the visible text on long links?

Comment: Yes, matching the actual URL is a piece of cake. The text that is displayed is another story, I can't figure out the logic behind it.

Comment: It seems to be basically keeping only the first 2 levels, and truncating the rest

Comment: @K Prime: Yes but what about http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test? It shows the entire string (5 levels).

Comment: Just testing! http://www.php.net/manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-/something/test

Comment: Looks like below a URI string length threshold, 2 path segments are shown. Beyond the threshold only the first segment is shown.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual-manual/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-/something/test

Comment: http://www.php.net/manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-/something/test

Comment: http://www.phps.net/manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-/something/test

Comment: http://www.php.net/manuals/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-/something/test

Comment: http://php.net/manuals/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en/something/test

Comment: http://php.net/manuals/en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en-en/something/test/

Comment: http://php.net/manuals/en/en/en/en/test

Comment: http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450 (testing again)

Comment: http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test

Comment: Think I got a solution that works pretty much the same as Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455#1971451

Comment: Testing FTP: ftp://user:pass@host.com:21/fhjfdfdhj/jhgfdhjdfhd/jfdfdhdfkjfdhfdkhdf/

Comment: http://php-php-php-php-php-php-php-php-php-php-php-php-php.net/manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals-manuals/test/

Comment: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guimarães

Comment: http://www.morangoscomaçúcar.com/

Comment: testing http://www.google.com

Comment: http://google.com/fdfdfdfd/dffdfdfd/dffddffd

Comment: http://www.google.com/1/2/3/4/5/index.php?q=lol#01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

Comment: http://www.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.google.com/1/2/3/4/5/index.php?q=lol#01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

Comment: http://www.example.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)_and_more_(parens)_eh

Comment: `http://aççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççç.com/` -> http://aççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççç.com/

Comment: http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test/ http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test

Comment: http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test/

Comment: http://www.google.com/index.php?q=lol#01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game)

Comment: What about that: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game))

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this out. The URL-matching regex pattern is from [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

```php
/**
 * Replace links in text with html links
 *
 * @param  string $text
 * @return string
 */
function auto_link_text($text)
{
   // a more readably-formatted version of the pattern is on http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
   $pattern  = '(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';

   $callback = create_function('$matches', '
       $url       = array_shift($matches);
       $url_parts = parse_url($url);

       $text = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
       $text = preg_replace("/^www./", "", $text);

       $last = -(strlen(strrchr($text, "/"))) + 1;
       if ($last < 0) {
           $text = substr($text, 0, $last) . "&hellip;";
       }

       return sprintf(\'<a rel="nofollow" href="%s">%s</a>\', $url, $text);
   ');

   return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $text);
}
```

**Input Text:**

```
This is my text.  I wonder if you know about asking questions on StackOverflow:
 Check This out http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior

 Also, base_convert php function?
http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450

http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php?wtf=hehe#52450
```

**Output Text:**

```html
This is my text.  I wonder if you know about asking questions on StackOverflow:
 Check This out <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior">stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/&hellip;</a>

 Also, base_convert php function?
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450">pt.php.net/manual/en/&hellip;</a>

<a rel="nofollow" href="http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php?wtf=hehe#52450">pt.php.net/manual/en/&hellip;</a>
```

Comment: returns NULL for me..? might create_function be a problem on some systems?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9838362/1048589 to see how you would convert this to use an anonymous function instead of create_function

Answer (score 24):

This is based on the same [daringfireball.net regular expression](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls), but adds a bit more logic than Eric Coleman's example, as well as configuration for maximum URL depth (SO seems to be 50), maximum path depth when URL is truncated (SO seems to be 2), and ellipsis character (`&hellip;`).

As far as I know this replicates all of the SO URL rewriting functionality, at least as far as what was discussed so far in the comments and responses here.

```
function auto_link_text($text) {
    $pattern  = '#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'auto_link_text_callback', $text);
}

function auto_link_text_callback($matches) {
    $max_url_length = 50;
    $max_depth_if_over_length = 2;
    $ellipsis = '&hellip;';

    $url_full = $matches[0];
    $url_short = '';

    if (strlen($url_full) > $max_url_length) {
        $parts = parse_url($url_full);
        $url_short = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $parts['host']) . '/';

        $path_components = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));
        foreach ($path_components as $dir) {
            $url_string_components[] = $dir . '/';
        }

        if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
            $url_string_components[] = '?' . $parts['query'];
        }

        if (!empty($parts['fragment'])) {
            $url_string_components[] = '#' . $parts['fragment'];
        }

        for ($k = 0; $k < count($url_string_components); $k++) {
            $curr_component = $url_string_components[$k];
            if ($k >= $max_depth_if_over_length || strlen($url_short) + strlen($curr_component) > $max_url_length) {
                if ($k == 0 && strlen($url_short) < $max_url_length) {
                    // Always show a portion of first directory
                    $url_short .= substr($curr_component, 0, $max_url_length - strlen($url_short));
                }
                $url_short .= $ellipsis;
                break;
            }
            $url_short .= $curr_component;
        }

    } else {
        $url_short = $url_full;
    }

    return "<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"$url_full\">$url_short</a>";
}
```

Sample Input:

```
This is my text.  I wonder if you know about asking questions on StackOverflow:
Check This out http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior

Also, base_convert php function?
http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450

http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php?wtf=hehe#52450

http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test

and http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test
```

Sample Output:

```
This is my text.  I wonder if you know about asking questions on StackOverflow:
Check This out <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/&hellip;</a> 

Also, base_convert php function?
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450">http://pt.php.net/manual/en/&hellip;</a> 

<a rel="nofollow" href="http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php?wtf=hehe#52450">http://pt.php.net/manual/en/&hellip;</a> 

<a rel="nofollow" href="http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test">http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test</a> 

and <a rel="nofollow" href="http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test">http://a.b/c/d/&hellip;</a>
```

Comment: +1, Indeed I was also testing the 50 length thingy and your answer is the most complete one to this question, I wish I had seen it before the bounty expired.

Comment: Seems to break on links like this: www.google.com - misses the schema part. I worked around that with  `  if ($matches[2] == "www.") {
    $url_full = "http://" . $url_full;
  }
`

Comment: thank you. this is the only one that works with this string "google(http://google.com)google" (edit: even stackoverflow's autolink cannot detect this string)

Answer (score 5):

This will convert the sample string to what you are after. I left out `title` as that comes from a different source than just a standalone URL and you said that was not important.

```
<?php
$urlInput="http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior";
preg_match('@http://(?:www\.)?(\S+/)\S*(?:\s|$)@i', $urlInput, $matches);
print('<a rel="nofollow" href="' . trim($matches[0]) . '">' . $matches[1] . '...</a>');
?>
```

Extend as needed to scan through your text.

If you want to match just a certain number of URL path elements, use this RE:

```
'@http://(?:www\.)?((?:\S+?/){1,3})\S*(?:\s|$)@i'
```

This will extract out up to 3 path elements (the host and up to two directories). You can vary the upper bound in `{1,3}` to define the maximum number of path elements you want.

Changed the ending `\S` to allow for zero matches.

Comment: +1, WOW, where did the magic come from? I was like "this isn't going to work" but surprisingly it almost did! I can't process Regex at this time but I'll try to understand it tomorrow.

Comment: Also, I said almost because it fails for the following URLs: `http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test` and `http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test`

Comment: http://a.b/c/d/e/f/test and http://a.b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/z/y/w/z/test

Comment: Also for URLs like `http://www.stackoverflow.com/` it fails: "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in I:\WWW\index.php on line 35 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in I:\WWW\index.php on line 35 ..."

Comment: Was adding the bounded check while the comments were being typed. This should work now for the longer URls.

Comment: Ok, this will now work if the URL just has the host name and trailing slash. However, it is much harder to make this work if there is no trailing slash.

Comment: Looks like you're showing `...` even when the URL is very short.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a predictable URL like SO then it should be easy to grab links with a regex and filter out the ones that match the pattern.  So if your URL is `http://example.com/stuff/1234` then finding `http://example.com/stuff/1234/how-to-mimic` would be pretty trivial with a regex.

```
<?php
preg_match('/http:\/\/example.com\/(\w*)\/(\d)[\/*]/', $text, $matches);

if (is_array($matches))
{
  foreach ($matches as $match)
  {
    // do something...
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Take `http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450` for instance. Check the comment on my question for the output.

Answer (score 3):

Based somewhat on Kevin Brock's answer, but allows configurable params (folder depth & URL length), and accepts URLs without trailing slashes:

```
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior';
$output = '';
$params = array (
    'length' => 10,
    'depth' => 2,
);
preg_match ('@http://(?:www\.)?([^/?# ]+)(/\S+)?(?=\s|$)@i', $url, $matches);
if (isset ($matches[2]))
{
    $parts = explode('/', substr($matches[2], 1));
    if (count($parts) > $params['depth'] && strlen($matches[1].$matches[2]) > $params['length'])
        $output = $matches[1].'/'.implode('/', array_slice($parts, 0, 2)).'/...';
    else
        $output = $matches[1].$matches[2];
}
else
    $output = $matches[1];

echo '<a href="'.$matches[0].'">'.$output.'</a>';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This answer seems to be the most flexible so far however it's pretty difficult to use it to replace URLs in free text since it does not use `preg_replace()`.

Comment: You could convert it to a function, and use that as callback to `preg_replace`

Answer (score 1):

See [Regex (regular expression) to match a URL](http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/):

> ```
> https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
> ```
>
> PHP Example: Automatically link URL's inside text.
>
> ```php
> $text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
> ```

Comment: That is a simple auto-linker, it does not mimic SO behavior.