# Can this snippet be further optimized / organized?

Tags: php, regex, string, explode, parse-url

From [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior) here at SO I've come up with the following PHP snippet:

```
$url = parse_url($url);

if (is_array($url))
{
    $depth = 2;
    $length = 50;

    if (array_key_exists('host', $url))
    {
        $result = preg_replace('~^www[.]~i', '', $url['host']);

        if (array_key_exists('path', $url))
        {
            $result .= preg_replace('~/+~', '/', $url['path']); // normalize a bit
        }

        if (array_key_exists('query', $url))
        {
            $result .= '?' . $url['query'];
        }

        if (array_key_exists('fragment', $url))
        {
            $result .= '#' . $url['fragment'];
        }

        if (strlen($result) > $length)
        {
            $result = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $result, $depth + 2), 0, $depth + 1)) . '/';

            if (strlen($result) > $length)
            {
                $result = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $result, $depth + 1), 0, $depth + 0)) . '/';
            }

            $result = substr($result, 0, $length) . '...';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Seems kinda hackish, specially the duplicate `if (strlen($result) > $length)` blocks of code. I've considered dropping `parse_url()` altogether, but I want to ignore the **scheme**, **user**, **pass** and **port**.

I'm wondering if you guys can come up with a more elegant / organized solution that has the same effect.

---

I just noticed, there is a bug - if `$depth != 2` the following block is affected:

```
if (strlen($result) > $length)
{
    $result = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $result, $depth + 2), 0, $depth + 1)) . '/';

    if (strlen($result) > $length)
    {
        $result = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $result, $depth + 1), 0, $depth + 0)) . '/';
    }

    $result = substr($result, 0, $length) . '...';
}
```

I think the best solution is to use a loop, I'll try to fix this ASAP. **:S**

---

Solved it, by replacing it with this new snippet:

```
if (strlen($result) > $length)
{
    for ($i = $depth; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        $result = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $result), 0, $i + 1)) . '/';

        if (strlen($result) <= $length)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    $result = substr($result, 0, $length) . '...';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the less cluttered version I came up with:

```
$url = preg_replace('~^www[.]~i', 'http://www.', array_shift($url));
$parts = parse_url($url);

if (is_array($parts))
{
    $depth = 2;
    $length = 50;

    if (array_key_exists('host', $parts))
    {
        $result = preg_replace('~^www[.]~i', '', $parts['host']);

        if (array_key_exists('path', $parts))
        {
            $result .= preg_replace('~/+~', '/', $parts['path']);
        }

        if (array_key_exists('query', $parts))
        {
            $result .= '?' . $parts['query'];
        }

        if (array_key_exists('fragment', $parts))
        {
            $result .= '#' . $parts['fragment'];
        }

        if (strlen($result) > $length)
        {
            while ($depth > 0)
            {
                $result = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $result), 0, $depth-- + 1)) . '/';

                if (strlen($result) <= $length)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            $result = substr($result, 0, $length) . '...';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters you could have:

```
if (is_array($url))
```

Repeat for all of your `=== true` operations. Why are you comparing types?

Comment: It's an habit, I always use strict comparisons. Fixed now.