# StackOverflow Style A Href Auto Linking in Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using the **below** function to search for text links and convert them to a hyperlink. First of all is it correct? It appears to work but do you know of a (perhaps malformed) url that would break this function?

My question is whether it is possible to get this to support port numbers as well, for example `stackoverflow.com:80/index` will not be converted as the port is not seen as a valid part of the url.

So in summary I am looking for Stackoverflow style url recognition, which I believe is a custom addition to Markdown.

```
  /**
   * Search for and create links from urls
   */
  static public function autoLink($text) {
    $pattern = "/(((http[s]?:\/\/)|(www\.))(([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]{2,2})?)\/?[a-z0-9._\/~#&=;%+?-]+[a-z0-9\/#=?]{1,1})/is";
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, " <a href='$1'>$1</a>", $text);
    // fix URLs without protocols
    $text = preg_replace("/href='www/", "href='http://www", $text);

    return $text;
  }
```

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Your function won't work for URLs to subdomains (ex `my.domain.com/mypage`)

Comment: How accurate do you want things to be? [www.ca](http://www.ca) completely valid url, but not one you expect to see regularly. There's plenty of things that ARE hostnames but definitely do not look like one.

Comment: Ideally covering all possibilities but I doubt anyone will point to a url like www.ca, would be interesting to see how stack overflow's one works it seems very good!

Comment: @Pez: Stack Overflow uses [MarkdownSharp](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/) with "Stack Exchange additions": http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. For PHP, the original Markdown project recommends the [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) port by Michel Fortin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also look at the answers to this question: [How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior)

---

I have ended up combining the answers I have got both at stack overflow and talking to colleagues. The below code is the best we could come up with.

```
/**
   * Search for and create links from urls
   */
  static public function autoLink($text) {
    $pattern = "/\b((?P<protocol>(https?)|(ftp)):\/\/)?(?P<domain>[-A-Z0-9\\.]+)[.][A-Z]{2,7}(([:])?([0-9]+)?)(?P<file>\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,\\.;]*)?(?P<parameters>\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,\\.;]*)?/ise";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, "' <a href=\"'.htmlspecialchars('$0').'\">$0</a>'", $text);

    // fix URLs without protocols
    $text = preg_replace("#href='www#i", "href='http://www", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("#href=['\"](?!(https?|ftp)://)#i", "href='http://", $text);

    return $text;
  }
```

Comment: This function screws up your html when there is no protocol: A simple link like www.google.com and info@google.com is converted into erroneous html code.

Comment: In the final version I put in some checks to prevent this. Unfortunately I no longer have access.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own autolinking routine, which is essentially the beginning of a custom markup engine, you might want to use an open source markup engine, as it is less likely to be vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks. One example of an open source markup engine for PHP is [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/), which has the ability to autolink URLs and essentially uses the same Markdown syntax that is in use at Stack Overflow.

One note: you should always escape HTML special characters using `htmlspecialchars()` before sticking the text into attributes or in the inner text of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/\b(?P<protocol>https?|ftp):\/\/(?P<domain>[-A-Z0-9.]+)(([:])?([0-9]+)?)(?P<file>\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?P<parameters>\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i";
```

will match:

**http://www.scroogle.org/index.html**

**http://www.scroogle.org:80/index.html?source=library**