# Detection - the title of the URL and the URL

Tags: php, url, detection

How to detect, if there is any URL in the text and title it has (if any)?

If there is one, then it should change the URL:

from: `http://stackoverflow.com`

into:

```
<detected:url="http://stackoverflow.com"/>
```

I need also to retrieve titles from external links like this example:

```
<title:http://stackoverflow.com/="the actual title from the stackoverflow"/>
```

Comment: This depends.  Do all URLs start with "http?"  What indicates a URL's title?

Comment: @tandu Not really because it will parse the data that user posted.
Title is the detected site url title from <title></title> tags.

Comment: Is that supposed to be XML? If so, it's not valid XML.

Comment: @icktoofay
Hehe, no its not XML :p

Comment: What are you detecting URLs from: HTML? XML? Text?

Comment: @Lucas just a question. Why did you prefix this question with "PHP" ?

Comment: @Nightfirecat
From my PHP variable taken from the database.

Comment: @genesis-φ
Because I need to add that to my PHP function. All should be PHP so I think it's a good prefix.

Comment: @Lucas: That's what tags are for, okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is for single URL case:**

```
$url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";

$check_result = get_detected_and_title( $url );


function get_detected_and_title( $url )
{
    $detected = '<detected:url="'.$url.'"/>';
    $title = '';
    $tmp_html = file_get_contents( $url );
    preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/', $tmp_html, $res);
    $title = '<title:'.$url.'="'.$res[1].'"/>';

    return array( $detected, $title );
}
```

Actually, after looking through SO's pages, I think this is more close to what you looking for. Although it needs some adjustment: [How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior)