# vBulletin URL replace code

Tags: php, url, replace, vbulletin

I was previously asking for a smiliar function, but no one of them are like the vBulletin 4 has.

I mean if I paste some URL's in the vBulletins text box it will replace them for example like this:

Input:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior
http://yahoo.com/
```

Output:

```
php - How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior - Stack Overflow
Yahoo!
```

And this is the best of all, because if the URL doesn't exist (or don't have  tags) it'll just stay with the URL path!

Input:

```
http://fake.url
```

Output:

```
http://fake.url
```

Then message BBCODE looks following:

```
[url=http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior]php - How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior - Stack Overflow[/url]
[url=http://yahoo.com/]Yahoo![/url]
[url]http://fake.url[/url]
```

How do they do that?
Is it possible to do with PHP/JS? If so, could you direct me how?

Kind Regards,

Lucas.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. parse the input to extract the URLs(there should be many related topics on SO)
2. request the URL's to get the contents of the `<title/>`
3. Build the BBCode regarding to the response

This can be done using PHP, JS-only will not be able, because it may not parse external documents.(But of course you can setup a proxy-script on serverside that requests the document and returns the title to javascript/AJAX)

Comment: I know what I have to do. The question is : how .
Also, this is not possible to request the URL using file_get_contents when URL is faked (does not exist).

Comment: What do you mean by "how", should I describe every single step? When file_get_contents() fails, simply don't replace the URL.

Comment: You can direct me, show me some scripts/examples, because I've searched a lot, and haven't see any good codes yet. I know I shouldnt replace the URL in case if the file_get_contents() fails, but then it throws up an error message. I think vBulletin is doing it other way, to grep the title from the <title> tags. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't have access to vbb4-source, but error-messages may be avoided using error_reporting(0) or the @-operator

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think is will be loong night for me. Rated up .