# How to minimize url link in search result

Tags: php, search

I have a search result like

> > **1. my title**
> >     my short description......
> >     
> >  http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html
> >     
> >     [http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/mypage.html?a=123123123&b=2342343](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html)

I want the url in this format

> > **1. my title**
> >     my short description......
> >     
> >  [http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/......./againandagainthisthat/mypage.html](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html)
> >     
> >     [http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/mypage.html?a....3123&b=2342343](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html)

Some text are skipped in middle of the link

I tried to google it but dont know the exact keyword to search..

**What ever my link is, if the length of that link is over 70 char ,lets say it has 100 then link is minimized to 70 char with ..... at the middle....**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior)

Comment: I neet in middle not at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (for original example):

```
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html';
$urlBitsArray = explode('/', $url);
$urlBitsCount = count($urlBitsArray);
$newUrl = implode('/', array($urlBitsArray['0'], $urlBitsArray['1'], $urlBitsArray['2'], $urlBitsArray['3'], '.....', $urlBitsArray[$urlBitsCount - 2], $urlBitsArray[$urlBitsCount - 1]));
echo $newUrl;
```

Basic if more than 70 take first 32 chars, last 32 chars and '......' in the middle:

```
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html ';

if (strlen($url) > 70) {
    $url = substr($url, 0, 31).'......'.substr($url, strlen($url) - 33);
}

echo $url;
```

Comment: Does not works for http://pt.php.net/function.base-convert.php?a=232323232323&b=234234234 this link

Comment: I think you need to be more specific of what you are after. Clearly define your conditions which will trigger shortening and then how you would like them to be shortened....

Comment: what ever my link is, if the length of that link is over 70 char ,lets say it has 100 then link is minimized to 70 char with ..... at the middle....

Comment: k, next edit has an example to do that (not some of the example urls you have given are in fact less than 70 chars)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/thisthat/againthisthat/againandagainthisthat/mypage.html";
$maxStringLength = 50;

if(strlen($string) > $maxStringLength)
{
    //remove http://
    if(strpos($string, "http://") === 0)
    {
        $string = substr($string, 7);
    }
    $bits = explode("/", $string);
    if(count($bits) > 2) //greater than www.stackoverflow.com/mypage.html
    {
        $string = implode("/", array($bits[0], $bits[1], '...', $bits[count($bits)-2], $bits[count($bits)-1]));
    }
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: Thanks but doesnot works for http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/mypage.html?a=123123123&b=2342343 this link