# jQuery Regex to return url

Tags: jquery, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

I have a string sent from the server that looks like this:

"Hey, have a look at this picture here http://example.com/fantastic.jpg, isn't it nice?"

I would like a regex function which does something like this:

```
function returnUrl(text) {
    regex here ...
    return url;
}
```

I am really bad with regex, so I am coming here asking for help. Please have a look at the picture below to get the idea of what I mean:

[image: stackOverflow automatic url recognize]

This is stackOverflow automatically changing my inserted text in a clickable URL, I suppose it's jQuery / regex.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, this regex should only work for images (jpg, png, etc.) not for all links.

Comment: https://www.google.at/?q=javascript+regex+url

Comment: Sorry, I'm too lazy to make a solution, you have to explode your text, and check every row with your amazing regexp, because of regexp has some problem with \n\r in text

Comment: My bad, I didn't reference that it should work for images only. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one will be :

```
https?://[\w-\.\?\#\/]+
```

A complete one (which I use) will be :

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```

And the last oe precisely come from [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

**EDIT**

A simple one for direct image links ([see here](http://regexr.com?31ve5))

```
https?://[\w-\.\/]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp)
```

Comment: ouch, my bad. Please have a look at the edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: The last one will be easy to modify for you. I agree, this is not the most complete one.

Comment: well, with some validation on the server side, it will work like a charm! thank you!

Comment: actually, there is a problem with this regex, I am using ` var imageUrl = url.match( /https?://[\w-\.\/]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp)/g ); ` but it gives an uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token illegal. What is this? Thank you.

Comment: This issue could come from a copy/paste : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal Try to rewrite it manually.

Comment: unbelieveable, still not working. now i'm getting: ` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ` with the code `  reg = http://https?://[\w-\.\/]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp);
 var imageUrl = url.match(reg); `

Comment: Now, you forgot to add delimiters : `reg = /https?://[\w-\.\/]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp)/; var imageUrl = url.match(reg);`

Comment: `var reg = /https?://[\w-\.\/]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp)/;` ... unexpected token illegal.... This is getting me crazy, really...

Comment: I mean, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Nphf/

Comment: Haha, sorry ^^' Using `/.../` delimiters, you need to escape `/` in your regex : `/https?:\/\/[\w-\.\/]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp)/` See here : http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/7Nphf/1/

Comment: pheew!! working now! thanks a lot!

Comment: uhm, it doesn't seem to recognize the % symbol, that is sometimes found in URLS, what should I add to the regex?

Comment: if you wanna add some symbols, do it at the end of this part : `[\w-\.\/]` (E.g : `[\w-\.\/\%]` - don't forget the backslash).

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
function returnUrl(text) {
     var reg = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
     var url = text.match(reg).toString();
     return url;
}
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/4vBLH/

Comment: check the edit. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1925455/471214).

URL regex from RegexBuddy library (use as **case-insensitive**):

```xml
\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

See it **[in action](http://regexr.com?31vdv)**.