# How do you make links clicks clickable with php and regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to parse our urls and make them clickable.. even if there is not http:// in front

So for example if we have

```
$text = "Hello this is a sample.com so go and parse that and also http://www.sample.com"
```

It would make sample.com and http://www.sample.com both clickable. How would I do that with regular expressions in php?

Comment: Check out this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior

Comment: That doesn't take care of links that don't have http:// but have .com .net at the end

Comment: You can mod the regex to allow the link to also start with not only www. or http but also nothing. #\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.]|)[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#

Comment: @CodeCrack without the `http://` or `www` part how would regex know that this is not a link `test.lol` ? Therefore the link provided by jthomas should help you.