# PHP autolink if not already linked

Tags: php, html

My question is similar to this question:

[How to mimic StackOverflow Auto-Link Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925455/how-to-mimic-stackoverflow-auto-link-behavior)

However this solution doesn't work for mixed content that may already contain links - any URLs already inside of A tags `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">My Link</a>` are being mangled into `<a href="<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>">My Link</a>`

Here's the desired behavior:

Before

```
https://stackoverflow.com/ is a wonderful URL.

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Has already been linked.</a>
```

After

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a> is a wonderful URL.

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Has already been linked.</a>
```

Comment: find the text that LOOKS like urls, then expand the code to look for html tags wrapping it. e.g. if you've got `http://` somewhere, then check that it isn't actually `<a href="http://` before you fire up the actual wrapping logic.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be worth parsing the block of text for HTML first, and then scan the text nodes for links, so you avoid nested links as well, such as `<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>` into `<a href="http://www.example.com"><a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load up the string as HTML in ta DOM parser, iterate over the text nodes, and check for a URL. Make sure the text node's parent isn't an `<a>` tag, so you know that the text you're getting is not already in a link. Now, find all of the URLs, convert them to `<a>` tags, and replace them in the DOM:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $str);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query('//text()') as $text) {
    if( !($text->parentNode->tagName == "a")) {
        $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
        $frag->appendXML( preg_replace('#(http://stackoverflow.com/)#', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text->data));
        $text->parentNode->replaceChild( $frag, $text);
    }
}
```

Note that this relies on a regex to identify URLs, which is a difficult task. I suggest finding one that suits your needs, as it is currently using:

```
#(http://stackoverflow.com/)#
```

However, given this input:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/ is a wonderful URL.

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Has already been linked.</a>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

It [produces this output](http://viper-7.com/gg396x):

```
<p><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a> is a wonderful URL. 

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Has already been linked.</a> 

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a></p>
```

Comment: Accepted answer. Created gist that fleshes out this idea. But will auto-link any URL, returns the entire document and handles some PHP compatibility issues: https://gist.github.com/leepowers/5529546