# Regex for url formatting (www.domain.tld to anchors)

Tags: php, regex, url, formatting, href

I'm currently developing a little browser-based Twitter widget.

Currently, I'm stuck with getting the URLs to work. I'm kinda newbie, when it comes to regex (I know, how to get parts of a string, but this one – tough one).

So, I need a regex that would search/replace

```
www.domain.tld -> <a href="http://www.domain.tld">http://www.domain.tld</a>
```

With/without http://, preferably.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how far I've got:

```
www\.(?:\S*)\.(?:\S{2,3})
```

It checks for www. at beginning, any non-witespace chars and top level domain (2 or three chars).

Comment: .info? .mobi? .museum? You should probably check for that.

Comment: Actually, I could even just check for non-whitespace chars, as mostly URLs have parameters too (?param=value&etc=1). Of course, at start I'll need to sanitize the input, for anti-XSS measures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in an ever going war against RegExes, I don't like them. So, do I'd do it like this instead:

```
function get_domain_from_anchor($anchor, $delimiter = '"') {
    return substr(strstr(strstr($anchor, $delimiter), $delimiter.'>', true), 8);
}

echo get_domain_from_anchor('<a href="http://www.domain.net">http://www.domain.net</a>');

// OUTPUTS: www.domain.net
```

Much better :D

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need the opposite thing. I have to convert from plaintext URLs to html anchors.

Comment: @Kristaps: Your question is a little unclear, what that regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is exactly what you're looking for: [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Some more information regarding extraction of URLs: [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

Comment: Thank you, I came up with
    ((?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(?:(?:[a-z0-9\&\.?=\-_\[\]\/])*))
Seems that'll work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [twitter-text-php](http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-php). It is ported to PHP from the official Twitter code.

From the README file:

```
$autolinker = new Twitter_Autolink();
$html = $autolinker->autolink("Tweet mentioning @mikenz and refuring to his list @mikeNZ/sports and website http://mikenz.geek.nz");
echo $html;
```