# Parse string to get an array of the URLs

Tags: regex, string, url, arrays, parsing

Imagine I have a string - something like this:

```
This is some really cool text about http://google.com/ and it also contains some urls like http://apple.com/ and its very nice! This is too long and I need to do some magic stuff to fix this very big problem. Oh no.
```

As you can see there are two URLs in the string and somehow, assuming I need some kind of REGEX I need to get an array of those URL's so I can manipulate them. Something like this...

```
Array()

- [0] = 'http://google.com/'
- [1] = 'http://apple.com/'
```

All help appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [extract urls from text in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

Comment: And since you didnt specify a language, here is a couple others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract+urls+out+of+text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should also work.

```
$string = 'ajskldfj http://google.ca jslfkjals s http://www.apple.com jalksf';
$pattern = '/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
https?:\/\/[^\s]+
```

Find something that starts with http:// or https://, then pull characters until we find whitespace.

Comment: For some reason php preg_match said i couldnt use \ as delimiter :(

Comment: Try just // instead of \/\/, some implementations don't require you to escape forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a regex pattern like the following:

```
'https?:\/\/(\w*?.)?(?P<domain>\w+).(\w+)/'
```