# Extract URL from string

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I'm trying to find a reliable solution to extract a url from a string of characters. I have a site where users answer questions and in the source box, where they enter their source of information, I allow them to enter a url. I want to extract that url and make it a hyperlink. Similar to how Yahoo Answers does it.

Does anyone know a reliable solution that can do this?

All the solutions I have found work for some URL's but not for others.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

John Gruber has [spent a fair amount of time](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) perfecting the "one regex to rule them all" for link detection. Using `preg_replace()` as mentioned in the other answers, using the following regex should be one of the most accurate, if not the most accurate, method for detecting a link:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

If you only wanted to match HTTP/HTTPS:

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Comment: For anyone who wants all the sub-patterns converted to be non capturing, and the forward slashes escaped: \b(?:(?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))

Comment: TLDs may have much more than 4 characters, see: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: And how do we use this regex within preg? I mean, because it has `"` and `'` the code doesn't work properly, like: `preg_match('(?i)\b......]))', $str)` - all code seems like it is commented.

Comment: Not working. Preg_match & preg_match_all failing everytime, even after removing single/double quotes

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+/', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $string);
```

It only matches http/https, but that's really the only protocol you want to turn into a link.  If you want others, you can change it like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(https?|ssh|ftp):\/\/[^\s"]+/', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $string);
```

Comment: You might also want to exclude `<` or apply `htmlspecialchars` on the matched string to avoid code injection.

Comment: Good, but if you look at the expression, it allows anything but white-space and `"`.  I believe that eliminates any HTML injection.

Comment: Bron: No, you are using the matched value not just as attribute value but also as the elements text content.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of edge cases with urls. Like url could contain brackets or not contain protocol etc. Thats why regex is not enough.

I created a PHP library that could deal with lots of edge cases: [Url highlight](https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight).

You could extract urls from string or directly highlight them.
Example:

```php
<?php

use VStelmakh\UrlHighlight\UrlHighlight;

$urlHighlight = new UrlHighlight();

// Extract urls
$urlHighlight->getUrls("This is example http://example.com.");
// return: ['http://example.com']

// Make urls as hyperlinks
$urlHighlight->highlightUrls('Hello, http://example.com.');
// return: 'Hello, <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.'
```

For more details see [readme](https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight/blob/master/README.md). For covered url cases see [test](https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight/blob/master/tests/UrlHighlightTest.php#L11).

Answer (score 0):

*Yahoo! Answers* does a fairly good job of link identification when the link is written properly and separate from other text, but it isn't very good at separating trailing punctuation.  For example `The links are http://example.com/somepage.php, http://example.com/somepage2.php, and http://example.com/somepage3.php.` will include commas on the first two and a period on the third.

But if that is acceptable, then patterns like this should do it:

```
\<http:[^ ]+\>
```

It looks like stackoverflow's parser is better.  Is is open source?

Comment: smarter, but still not perfect. misses things like ssh+svn.

Answer (score -1):

This code is worked for me.

```
function makeLink($string){

/*** make sure there is an http:// on all URLs ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);
/*** make all URLs links ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$string);
/*** make all emails hot links ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>",$string);

return $string;
}
```

Comment: Why are you limiting tld to 3 characters? Have a look at: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db