# Capture every URL in text

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regex to find url in a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461702/regex-to-find-url-in-a-text)

Can I get a regular expression that will capture every URL from a string, I'd like to be able to pop a domain in the expression at some stage to limit captures. Much obliged.

Comment: what about "var regex = /http[s]?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2}/" ?