# How to with extract url from tweet using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

Ok so i'm executing the following line of code in javascript

```
RegExp('(http:\/\/t.co\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{8}').exec(tcont);
```

where tcont is equal to some string like 'Test tweet to http://t.co/GXmaUyNL' (the content of a tweet obtained by jquery).

However it is returning, in the case above for example, 'http://t.co/GXmaUyNL,http://t.co/'.

This is frustracting because I want the url without the bit on the end - after and including the comma.

Any ideas why this is appearing? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex to find url in a text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461702/regex-to-find-url-in-a-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get rid of the parens in the pattern - they're unnecessary:

```
RegExp('http:\/\/t.co\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{8}').exec(tcont);
```

Second, a regex match returns an array of matching groups - you want the first item in it (the entire match):

```
var match = RegExp('http:\/\/t.co\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{8}').exec(tcont);
if(match) {
    var result = match[0];
}
```

The reason you had "a part on the end" is because your result is *actually* an array - the parens you had in the expression were resulting in an extra matching group (the portion they were around), which would be `match[1]`.

Comment: Excellent, that worked thank you so much - I'm not all that experienced with regex so that really helps.

Comment: I think the `.` should be escaped.

Comment: @pimvdb technically, yes, but since all URLs on Twitter get transformed into `t.co` URLs, it doesn't actually matter in this case.

Comment: @Amber: Very true, I was just nitpicking :)

Comment: pimvdb is absolutely correct: the `.` should be escaped. In a regular expression, `.` matches a single character. In this particular example, it will of course match a literal `.` in the source. However, the regex would also match `http://tico/GXmaUyNL` (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `RegExp('http:\/\/t\.co\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{8}').exec(tcont);`