# jQuery: How can i replace some text by another text in a $('#myId').attr('value') of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i replace some text by another text in a `$('#myId').attr('value')` of a textarea ?

I tried something like this :

```
$(function() {
    var selection;
    var replaceStr;

    var prependStr = "";
    var appendStr = "";

    var temp = "";

    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'underline')
        {
            prependStr = "<span style = 'text-decoration: underline;'>";
            appendStr = "</span>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'italic')
        {
            prependStr = "<span style = 'font-style: italic;'>";
            appendStr = "</span>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'bold')
        {
            prependStr = "<span style = 'font-weight: bold;'>";
            appendStr = "</span>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'center')
        {
            prependStr = "<span style = 'text-align: center;'>";
            appendStr = "</span>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'link')
        {
            prependStr = "<a href = ''>";
            appendStr = "</a>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'img')
        {
            prependStr = "<img src = '";
            appendStr = "' />";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'h1')
        {
            prependStr = "<h1>";
            appendStr = "</h1>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'h2')
        {
            prependStr = "<h2>";
            appendStr = "</h2>";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'h3')
        {
            prependStr = "<h3>";
            appendStr = "</h3>";
        }

        $('#page').focus();
        selection = window.getSelection();

        if(selection != '')
        {
            replaceStr = prependStr+selection+appendStr;

            temp = $('#page').attr('value');
            temp.replace(selection, replaceStr);//Not working

            $('#page').attr('value', temp);
        }
    });

});
```

The whole code is working, exept the function .replace(). I googled a lot of things, but i didn't found a function to do this on a $('#page').attr('value').

Comment: Using val() and replace() functions like here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11585664/3558900

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

Comment: var textarea = $('#page');
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(selection, replaceStr));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#page').attr('value');` returns a string, and strings are inmutable, that means when you do `temp.replace(selection, replaceStr);` it doesn't actually change the string object, all it does is create another string object, so it doesn't change the value of the textarea.

Yo could get what you want with

```
var textarea = $('#page');
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(selection, replaceStr));
```

By the way, `jqueryElement.val(value)` is the equivalent to `jqueryElement.attr('value', value)` wich is used to **set** the value.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i didn't understood how replace() was working at all !

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

temp.replace(selection, replaceStr) does not change the variable "temp". It returns a new string.

Do sth like this:
temp = temp.replace(selection, replaceStr);
$('#page').attr('value', temp);

Comment: I did saw this link when i was googling, but didn't understand it, thanks.