# R script file encoding (R Studio)

Tags: r, encoding

Which file encoding do I have to use to be able to save this vector ([Matching complex URLs within text blocks (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059050/matching-complex-urls-within-text-blocks-r/16136857#16136857)) correctly in a R script? The special characters and Chinese signs seem to make things somehow complicated.

```
x <-   c("http://foo.com/blah_blah",
        "http://foo.com/blah_blah/",
        "(Something like http://foo.com/blah_blah)",
        "http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)",
         "http://foo.com/more_(than)_one_(parens)",
         "(Something like http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia))",
         "http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1",
         "http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1",
         "http://foo.com/unicode_(✪)_in_parens",
         "http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens",
         "http://foo.com/blah_blah.",
         "http://foo.com/blah_blah/.",
         "<http://foo.com/blah_blah>",
         "<http://foo.com/blah_blah/>",
         "http://foo.com/blah_blah,",
         "http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=364.",
         "http://✪df.ws/1234",
         "rdar://1234",
         "rdar:/1234",
         "x-yojimbo-item://6303E4C1-6A6E-45A6-AB9D-3A908F59AE0E",
         "message://%3c330e7f840905021726r6a4ba78dkf1fd71420c1bf6ff@mail.gmail.com%3e",
         "http://➡.ws/䨹",
         "www.c.ws/䨹",
         "<tag>http://example.com</tag>",
         "Just a www.example.com link.",
         "http://example.com/something?with,commas,in,url, but not at end",
         "What about <mailto:gruber@daringfireball.net?subject=TEST> (including brokets).",
         "mailto:name@example.com",
         "bit.ly/foo",
         "“is.gd/foo/”",
         "WWW.EXAMPLE.COM",
         "http://www.asianewsphoto.com/(S(neugxif4twuizg551ywh3f55))/Web_ENG/View_DetailPhoto.aspx?PicId=752",
         "http://www.asianewsphoto.com/(S(neugxif4twuizg551ywh3f55))",
         "http://lcweb2.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/h?pp/horyd:@field(NUMBER+@band(thc+5a46634))")
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Which encoding do you use at the moment? What does `getOption("encoding")` give you? I tried `source('file.R', encoding="native.enc")` and `source('file.R', encoding="unknown")` with your script as `file.R` and the vector could be read.

Comment: I'm not sure if the "special characters and Chinese" I see now are the same as what you see because it depends on the encoding of our browsers (mostly UTF-8). I guess maybe checking your browser's encoding and changing your IDE's to the same one will do.

Answer (score 1):

Running your example,

```
source('file.R', encoding="unknown")
```

works fine and saving as R object and reloading works as well:

```
 save(x, file='kk.Rd')
 load('kk.Rd')
```

You can get all different encodings with `iconvlist()` and test them all, for example:

```
vals <- lapply(iconvlist(), function(x)
                      tryCatch(source('file.R', encoding=x),                
                               error=function(e)return(NULL)))
```

with `file.R` being your script, and then

```
iconvlist()[which(!sapply(vals, function(x)is.null(x)))]
```

gives you all encodings where no error was thrown while loading.

Does this help?

Comment: I tried various encodings manually and everytime I open the R script the mentioned signs are displayed wrongly (i.e. substituted by other signs). That means, there is never an error, but the content is still wrong.

Comment: When I open the file in Rstudio, it looks like all symbols are displayed correctly. For which symbols does it fail? On which platform are you working?