# JS: Convert plain text url (within blob) to link or iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking for a javascript solution for converting plain text urls (inside text blobs) into anchor links or iframe videos, on the fly (or on page load). Here's a rails example of what I'm looking for:
https://github.com/dejan/auto_html

Examples:

**Picture or Non-video url**

Before: `http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/`

After: `<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/">http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/</a></p>`

**Video**

Before: `http://youtu.be/QYEC4TZsy-Y`

After: `<p><iframe width="410" height="270" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QYEC4TZsy-Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>`

**In Use**

Before:
The quick brown fox,`http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/`, jumps over a lazy dog.

After: The quick brown fox,`<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/">http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/</a>`, jumps over a lazy dog.

Comment: `return '<p><a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a></p>';`? What's the problem?

Comment: How would you differentiate `url`s that, which one is  video link and which one is an image and which one is just a link to a page ? One way, amybe you can find out the link type (video/image) by checking the domain names, for example, if alink contains `youtube` then it's a video link and so on.

Comment: More specifically to check whether the url is from youtube or vimeo and if so add iframe, but if url isn't then add link like JB Nizet's comment.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my comment, if your link contains `youtube/viemo` then it's a video link and so..

Comment: Wondering if there is a nicely packaged github project that is already doing this, and perhaps looking up flickr, youtube, vimeo, etc.. titles to add to the html alt title attributes.

Comment: I added another Example above of how the plain text needs to be translated on the fly.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the problem is: detecting URLs inside text? Replacing URL with a link? Separating video URLs and non-video URLs? Update the dom with new content?

Comment: Detecting the URLs inside text and separating them with an example of the dom update.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this ([An Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQJZZ/1/))

```
var linkGenerator = {
    youtube:function(link){
        var ifr = document.createElement('iframe'),
        p = document.createElement('p');
        ifr.src = link;
        ifr.frameborder = 0;
        ifr.allowfullscreen = true;
        ifr.width = '410';
        ifr.height = '270';
        p.appendChild(ifr);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(p);
    },
    flickr:function(link){
        var lnk = document.createElement('a'),
        p = document.createElement('p');
        lnk.href = link;
        lnk.innerHTML = 'image';
        p.appendChild(lnk);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(p);
    }
};

var link1 = 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/';
var link2 = 'http://youtube.com/embed/QYEC4TZsy-Y';
if(link1.match(/flickr/i)) {
    linkGenerator.flickr(link1);
}
if(link2.match(/youtube/i)) {
    linkGenerator.youtube(link2);
}
```

This is just an idea, you may extend it and add more functions for more domain names. Also, notice that, I've used `http://youtu.be/embed/QYEC4TZsy-Y` instead of `http://youtu.be/QYEC4TZsy-Y`, because of `'X-Frame-Options' set to 'SAMEORIGIN'`.

**Update :** (To re-make the `youtube` url with `embed`)

```
var link2 = 'http://youtube.com/QYEC4TZsy-Y';
if(link2.match(/youtube/i)) {
    var vdoId = link2.split('/').pop();
    link2 = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vdoId;
    linkGenerator.youtube(link2);
}
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQJZZ/2/)

Comment: Sweet! One question. If var link1 = 'The quick brown fox, `http://www.flickr.com/photos/volume12/3820189650/`, jumps over a lazy dog.'; how would I get the url out to run through the generator?

Comment: Sorry! didn't get it, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: What if the urls are inside of large text blobs. How would you find each url?

Comment: Could the url be found by whether or not a string has http or https? Then it could check if it has youtube in it?

Comment: You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: [You may use this](https://github.com/ljosa/urlize.js), look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10498273/741747).

Comment: @Jeffrey, Take Care, leaving now :-)