# How to find a link in some text?

Tags: java, regex, rfc

I have a **string in java** that might or might not contain some **link** (url like www.google.com, stackoverflow.com, stanford.edu, etc). Now I want to search in the string if it contains any link. I have two problems here:

1. What to search while searching for links. I mean link may or **may not contain www, https, com, etc**, so how to differentiate it from text. What is the RFC specifications for links?
2. Which **function** to use in  Java for searching that regex? I am fairly new to Java.

Comment: post some examples of what you want to match and what you won't.

Comment: [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) defines the syntax of a generic URL. [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), section 3.2, defines the HTTP URL scheme.

Comment: examples can be any url...If there is some link in text I need to find it..

Comment: Is it homework? Because the first Google hit gave a nice example including Java code.

Comment: Or here are some nice links to regexes you could use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461702

Comment: Thanks rve!!no not a homework!!I wanted some more informative answers related to rfc and using some expression to detect instead of simply divide the string and check!!

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

- Split the whole string by delimiting it by spaces.
- Try to form URL using the each item.

  ```
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;

  // Replaces URLs with html hrefs codes
     public class URLInString {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s = args[0];
       // separete input by spaces ( URLs don't have spaces )
       String [] parts = s.split("\\s");
       // Attempt to convert each item into an URL.   
       for( String item : parts ){ 
          try {
             URL url = new URL(item);
             // If possible then replace with anchor...
             System.out.print("<a href=\"" + url + "\">"+ url + "</a> " );    
             }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 // If there was an URL that was not it!...
                 System.out.print( item + " " );
             }
        }            
    }
  ```

Comment: any other solution..this is a long procedure with for loop if I have to do it for thousands of string this won't be appropriate..What I was looking for is some regex expressionfor url that can be checked in string...although I liked your solution as its simple and tricky ...

Comment: You were missing a brace after the for, btw.

Comment: regex has loops to just not written in your app code. you should try more than one apprcoah and time them if u need performance

Comment: Still, it is bad practice to rely on exceptions (which may be quite slow, since they need to fill in stack-trace information) for flow execution. Loops are unavoidable, but slow loops can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This does not rely on exceptions to find URL validity, just on locating URLs by regex:

```
/**
 * Fills the arraylist urls with all valid (and a few invalid) urls in 's'
 */
void findUrlsInString(String s, ArrayList<String> urls) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "(([a-z]+):((//)|(\\\\))+)?[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        urls.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

The regex is not perfect; I have adapted it [from here](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/core-java-tutorial/extract-urls-using-java-regular-expressions), but I could not find a canonical Java regex for URLs. You *can* craft invalid URLs that will pass this regex, but it will require a slight effort.