# How can i make URL clickable and get youtube code from it

Tags: php, html, youtube

I am getting a string from database and echo it with php. There is a youtube link in this string and after i echo it i want it to be clickable. Also i want to get the youtube code which is at the end of the link. How can i make it?

Example text: This video is very interesting. Watch it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkLTxsAhURw. I loved it!

Thank you.

Comment: what is the string you are getting from the database?

Comment: It's the example text.

Comment: You can put the youtube link in the href attribute of the <a> tag and place the <img> tag inside the <a> tag

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390556/extract-url-from-string to extract the URL. Then wrap it with `<a>` like any other hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing just the text you can echo:

```
<a href=".$row['YOUTUBELINK'].">".$row['YOUTUBELINK']."</a>.
```

This will produce a clickable link. It's hard to help you without code though.

Comment: Thanks, but i want it to be like the example above. The actual link must be clickable. I dont know how to make php understand that its a link when it get the whole text from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get youtube code from youtube link using following script.

```
$youtube_link  = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkLTxsAhURw';
$youtube_code = substr($youtube_link, strpos($youtube_link, "=") + 1);
echo $youtube_code;
```