# Extract url with .swf in the end from string

Tags: php

I want to extract a url ending with .swf using php.

**EXAMPLE**

```
TEST TEST TEST http://website.com/example.swf
```

I want to get the url with the *.swf*

I used a function `preg_replace()`

```
preg_replace('!http://[^?#]+\.(?:swf|SWF)!Ui','', $content);
```

but it extract the url + some words after the url

THANKS..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390556/extract-url-from-string

Comment: thnk You @Odilon Grisi but i went to get the url with .swf not any url in the string

Comment: why not use parse_url? http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: I think that parse_url work with urls not strings it give you an array contain informations from url like host ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clarification on what you need i think this will help you.

```
preg_match_all('#(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+\.swf) (?P<description>[^\n]+)#uiD', $content, $results);
$data = [];
foreach($results['url'] as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = [
         'url' => $value,
         'description' => $results['description'][$key]
    ];
}

// Here you can put your code for saving the data you want.
// if you need to replace the content urls with the <object> tag:
$content = preg_replace('#(https?://[^\s]+\.swf)#uiD', '<object src="$1"></object>', $content);
```

Comment: it get the seems thing

Comment: Please post an example text you use, what happens after the preg_replace. the \b should do the job and not touch anything other then the url

Comment: I think that the problem is not from your function i need another function in php not preg_replace like explod or something else , THANKS

Comment: What exactly you try to do?

Comment: what want to do is geting the content of post wordpress and extract the url that end with .swf and put it in <object> and get other text and put it in description under the object

Comment: Then why use preg_replace? If you want to receive the url, use preg_match_all

Comment: Or use the preg_replace with '<object src="$1">' as second parameter

Comment: So how to use preg_match_all in this case

Comment: If all you need is to replace the text with an object tag, use my last answer

Comment: no i want to store description in one variable and url that end with .swf in another variable. that what i want exactly

Comment: And from where you get the description?

Comment: from the content of the post in wordpress.

Comment: all posts are like this                                                     

-------------------------------------
[IMAGE OF THE POST]

http://website.com/example.swf

DESCRIPTION EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION EXAMPLE .....
------------------------------------------------------------------