# Regular expression to find URLs within a string

Tags: regex, string, url

Does anyone know of a regular expression I could use to find URLs within a string? I've found a lot of regular expressions on Google for determining if an entire string is a URL but I need to be able to search an entire string for URLs.  For example, I would like to be able to find `www.google.com` and `http://yahoo.com` in the following string:

```
Hello www.google.com World http://yahoo.com
```

I am not looking for specific URLs in the string. I am looking for ALL of the URLs in the string which is why I need a regular expression.

Comment: For PHP: `preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);` from https://stackoverflow.com/q/910912/1066234

Comment: you're example missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Answer (score 298):

This is the one I use

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])
```

Works for me, should work for you too.

Comment: The inclusion of `&amp;` in the expression is fishy. Where is this supposed to be used in?

Comment: Don't forget to escape the forward slashes.

Comment: It's 2017, and unicode domain names are all over the place. `\w` may not match international symbols (depends on regex engine), the range is needed instead: `a-zA-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF`.

Comment: This is fine for general purpose, but there are many cases that it doesn't catch. This enforces that your links are prefixed with a protocol. If choose to ignore protocols, endings of emails are accepted as it is the case with test@testing.com.

Comment: shouldn't `[\w_-]` be `[\w-]`? because `\w` matches `_` already. per [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word)

Comment: The answer provided by @Stefan Henze works much better (read: detects more valid URLs) than this one.

Comment: Upvoted but This answer does not work what the question is asking `www.yahoo.com`. `"""(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?""".r.findAllIn("www.google.com").toList` . ALSO LACKS EXPLANATION for answer

Comment: I did a slight change to allow http://, https:// or ftp:// to be optional:  `^((http|ftp|https)://)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?`

Comment: Using the regex provided by @JustinLevene did not have the proper escape sequences on the back-slashes. Updated to now be correct, and added in condition to match the FTP protocol as well: Will match to all urls with or without protocols, and with out without "www." `^((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?`

Comment: Updated to include the `://` in the returned string: `(http|ftp|https)(:\/\/)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?`

Comment: `((http|ftp|https)\:\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?` https://regex101.com/r/4XfRNi/2

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Imho the `(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+)` should be optional, though, in order to catch links like `http://localhost/foo` (or any other hostname within the local search domain). Also I have removed the `?` from the last character range as I think it is more likely to be a normal punctuation character.

Comment: The problem here is someone can write shorthanded URLS, such as "example.com"

Comment: If things are shortened or don't include a protocol (www.example.com, somebody@example.com), it's not a URL, it's a domain name or an email address. That may be what you need but it's not a URI.

Answer (score 68):

Guess no regex is perfect for this use. I found a pretty solid one [here](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/)

```
/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm
```

Some differences / advantages compared to the other ones posted here:

- It does *not* match email addresses
- It does match localhost:12345
- It won't detect something like `moo.com` without `http` or `www`

See [here](http://regexr.com/3amq5) for examples

Comment: it matches www.e 
This is not a valid url

Comment: The `g` option isn't valid in all regular expression implementations (e.g. Ruby's built-in implementation).

Comment: This one worked a lot better, thanks!

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Answer (score 48):

```
text = """The link of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string
Also there are some urls: www.google.com, facebook.com, http://test.com/method?param=wasd, http://test.com/method?param=wasd&params2=kjhdkjshd
The code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list."""

urls = re.findall('(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-&?=%.]+', text)
print(urls)
```

Output:

```
[
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string', 
    'www.google.com', 
    'facebook.com',
    'http://test.com/method?param=wasd',
    'http://test.com/method?param=wasd&params2=kjhdkjshd'
]
```

Comment: Kotlin
 val urlRegex = "(?:(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/)?[\\w/\\-?=%.]+\\.[\\w/\\-?=%.]+"

Comment: Misses `&` parameters in the url. e.g. `http://test.com/method?param=wasd&param2=wasd2` misses param2

Comment: also lacks support for URLs with #

Comment: @TrophyGeek I think you just copied the regex from the first comment, and Akshay forgot to include the `&`. The right version would be: `val urlRegex = "(?:(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/)?[\\w/\\-?=%.]+\\.[\\w/\\-&?=%.]+"`

Comment: This also thinks `hello...` is a URL

Comment: you're example missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Answer (score 14):

Wrote one up myself:

```js
let regex = /([\w+]+\:\/\/)?([\w\d-]+\.)*[\w-]+[\.\:]\w+([\/\?\=\&\#\.]?[\w-]+)*\/?/gm
```

It works on ALL of the following domains:

```
https://www.facebook.com
https://app-1.number123.com
http://facebook.com
ftp://facebook.com
http://localhost:3000
localhost:3000/
unitedkingdomurl.co.uk
this.is.a.url.com/its/still=going?wow
shop.facebook.org
app.number123.com
app1.number123.com
app-1.numbEr123.com
app.dashes-dash.com
www.facebook.com
facebook.com
fb.com/hello_123
fb.com/hel-lo
fb.com/hello/goodbye
fb.com/hello/goodbye?okay
fb.com/hello/goodbye?okay=alright
Hello www.google.com World http://yahoo.com
https://www.google.com.tr/admin/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
https://google.com.tr/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
http://google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
ftp://google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
www.google.com.tr/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
www.google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
drive.google.com/test/subPage?qs1=sss1&qs2=sss2&qs3=sss3#Services
https://www.example.pl
http://www.example.com
www.example.pl
example.com
http://blog.example.com
http://www.example.com/product
http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2
http://www.example.com#up
http://255.255.255.255
255.255.255.255
shop.facebook.org/derf.html
```

You can [see how it performs here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8M0MqB/1) and adjust as needed

Comment: Your regex missed this when I tested it. It only caught part of the URL:
shop.facebook.org/derf.html

Comment: @DavidRector Thanks! You are absolutely correct. I have updated the regex string and regex101 url based on your feedback. Added a \. at the end of the second last pair of square brackets [ ]

Comment: This also matches any string of the form `alphanum_char.alphanum_char`, for example, `a.r`, `b.4`, `7.e`, etc. These aren't valid URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately this also matches times - 09:00

Comment: your regex missed the case of the protocol is not specified as //www.leboncoin.fr

Comment: it also matches www://rfg.com, too many invalid matches, I suggest to not use this.

Answer (score 12):

None of the solutions provided here solved the problems/use-cases I had.

What I have provided here, is the best I have found/made so far. I will update it when I find new edge-cases that it doesn't handle.

```
\b
  #Word cannot begin with special characters
  (?<![@.,%&#-])
  #Protocols are optional, but take them with us if they are present
  (?<protocol>\w{2,10}:\/\/)?
  #Domains have to be of a length of 1 chars or greater
  ((?:\w|\&\#\d{1,5};)[.-]?)+
  #The domain ending has to be between 2 to 15 characters
  (\.([a-z]{2,15})
       #If no domain ending we want a port, only if a protocol is specified
       |(?(protocol)(?:\:\d{1,6})|(?!)))
\b
#Word cannot end with @ (made to catch emails)
(?![@])
#We accept any number of slugs, given we have a char after the slash
(\/)?
#If we have endings like ?=fds include the ending
(?:([\w\d\?\-=#:%@&.;])+(?:\/(?:([\w\d\?\-=#:%@&;.])+))*)?
#The last char cannot be one of these symbols .,?!,- exclude these
(?<![.,?!-])
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this javascript friendly? As named capturing groups are not fully functional there, so the protocol value check does not validate.

Answer (score 9):

I think this regex pattern handle precisely what you want

```
/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/
```

and this is an snippet example  to extract Urls:

```
// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string to filter goes here.";

// Check if there is a url in the text
preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $url,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Answer (score 8):

If you have to be strict on selecting links, I would go for:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

For more infos, read this:

[An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

Comment: Don't do that. http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html
It'll kill your app...

Answer (score 7):

All of the above answers are not match for Unicode characters in URL, for example: [http://google.com?query=đức+filan+đã+search](http://google.com?query=%C4%91%E1%BB%A9c+filan+%C4%91%C3%A3+search)

For the solution, this one should work:

```
(ftp:\/\/|www\.|https?:\/\/){1}[a-zA-Z0-9u00a1-\uffff0-]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9u00a1-\uffff0-]{2,}(\S*)
```

Comment: Unicode characters were forbidden as per the RFC 1738 on URLs (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html). They would have to be percent encoded to be standards compliant - although I think it may have changed more recently - worth reading  https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/

Comment: @mrswadge I just cover the cases. We're not sure if all people care about the standard.
Thank you for your info.

Comment: Only this one worked perfectly for me having urls such as 
"http://www.example.com"
"www.exmaple.com"
"https://example.com"
"ftp://example.co.in"
"http://www.exmaple.com/?q='me'"

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Comment: @Adrien Parrochia I don't think it's valid, isn't it?

Comment: //www.google.fr  is valid. When you're on a website, if the website don't know if it's open with a http or http protocol, if you have  remove the protocol from the link, the navigator  will open the link with the current protocol.  This avoids switching from a secure protocol (https) to an insecure protocol (in an iframe for example)

Answer (score 6):

I used below regular expression to find url in a string:

```
/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` is really poor for matching TLD, see official list: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Answer (score 6):

I found [this](https://www.regextester.com/96504) which covers most sample links, including subdirectory parts.

Regex is:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?
```

Comment: When I tried this, the ends of sentences were marked as a match.
In the above sentence, the last word "match" and the period were matched.

Answer (score 4):

Short and simple. I have not tested in javascript code yet but It looks it will work:

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(([\w.-]*)\.([\w]*))
```

[Code on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/B5hYwv/2)

[image: Code preview]

Comment: I liked your regex because it was exactly what I was looking for: I needed to identify and strip URLs out of some text, not validate. Worked in rails.

Comment: @Dagmar I am glad to hear that :)

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Comment: You are right @AdrienParrochia. When I posted this, I didn't check for it. Maybe I can do it later.

Answer (score 4):

Using the regex provided by @JustinLevene did not have the proper escape sequences on the back-slashes. Updated to now be correct, and added in condition to match the FTP protocol as well: Will match to all urls with or without protocols, and with out without "www."

Code: `^((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/uQ9aL4/65

Answer (score 4):

**IMPROVED**

Detects Urls like these:

- https://www.example.pl
- http://www.example.com
- [www.example.pl](http://www.example.pl)
- example.com
- http://blog.example.com
- http://www.example.com/product
- http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2
- http://www.example.com#up
- http://255.255.255.255
- 255.255.255.255
- http:// [www.site.com:8008](http://www.site.com:8008)

Regex:

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
```

Please note that working with URLs and domain validation can be complex, and regex alone may not cover all edge cases. For more comprehensive URL validation, it's recommended to use specialized libraries or built-in URL validation functions provided by your programming language or framework.

Comment: This will detect some expression such as "A.D." or "B.C." as urls though.

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set  //www.google.fr

Answer (score 4):

Here a little bit more optimized regexp:

```
(?:(?:(https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)|([\w\-_]+(?:\.|\s*\[dot\]\s*[A-Z\-_]+)+))([A-Z\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[A-Z\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#]){2,6}?
```

Here is test with data: https://regex101.com/r/sFzzpY/6

[image]

Comment: Your test shows some of your URL's are not being detected fully. This entire string should be marked as a match:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619430/cant-get-newest-data-from-dao-unless-restart-the-app

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set : //www.google.fr

Answer (score 4):

Wasn't easy one, but managed to compose a short and efficient regex pattern to match URLs, also captures email addresses. Hope that works for you.

```
((\bhttp(|s)|ftp|file):\/\/)|\bwww[ ]*\.[ ]*([a-zA-Z0-9%:?#@\/=_-]*)|([a-zA-Z0-9%:.?#@\/=_-]*)[ ]*\.[ ]*(com|eu|org|co|uk|pdf|etc)
```

This can be tested here regexr.com

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set  //www.google.fr

Answer (score 3):

If you have the url pattern, you should be able to search for it in your string. Just make sure that the pattern doesnt have `^` and `$` marking beginning and end of the url string. So if P is the pattern for URL, look for matches for P.

Comment: This is the regex I found that verifies if an entire string is a URL. I took out the ^ at the beggining and the $ at the end like you said and it still didn't work.  What am I doing wrong?   

`^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$`

Comment: It might help if you showed what language you're using. Either way, be sure to check `http://regexpal.com/`; there you can test different expressions against your string until you get it right.

Comment: @user758263 - do you really need such a complex regex for the url? Depends on what the possible urls you might actually find. Also see http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for trying out regex. They also have hundreds of samples on the right under the `Community` tab including ones for urls

Comment: I'm trying to look for all possible URLs and I'm using C++. Thanks for the links entonio and manojlds. The gskinner site was especially helpful since it had samples.

Answer (score 3):

A probably too simplistic, but working method might be:

```
[localhost|http|https|ftp|file]+://[\w\S(\.|:|/)]+
```

I tested it on Python and as long as the string parsing contains a space before and after and none in the url (which I have never seen before) it should be fine.

[Here is an online ide demonstrating it](https://regex101.com/r/um32yD/1)

However here are some benefits of using it:

- It recognises `file:` and `localhost` as well as ip addresses
- It will **never** match without them
- It does not mind unusual characters such as `#` or `-` (see url of this post)

Comment: you're regex missed the case of the protocol is not set //www.google.fr

Answer (score 3):

I use this Regex:

```
/((\w+:\/\/\S+)|(\w+[\.:]\w+\S+))[^\s,\.]/ig
```

It works fine for many URLs, like:
http://google.com, https://dev-site.io:8080/home?val=1&count=100, www.regexr.com, localhost:8080/path, ...

Answer (score 3):

I liked Stefan Henze 's solution but it would pick up 34.56. Its too general and I have unparsed html. There are 4 anchors for a url;

www ,

http:\ (and co) ,

. followed by letters and then / ,

or letters . and one of these: https://ftp.isc.org/www/survey/reports/current/bynum.txt .

I used lots of info from this thread. Thank you all.

```
"(((((http|ftp|https|gopher|telnet|file|localhost):\\/\\/)|(www\\.)|(xn--)){1}([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?)|(([\\w_-]{2,200}(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)*))((\\.[\\w_-]+\\/([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?)|(\\.((org|com|net|edu|gov|mil|int|arpa|biz|info|unknown|one|ninja|network|host|coop|tech)|(jp|br|it|cn|mx|ar|nl|pl|ru|tr|tw|za|be|uk|eg|es|fi|pt|th|nz|cz|hu|gr|dk|il|sg|uy|lt|ua|ie|ir|ve|kz|ec|rs|sk|py|bg|hk|eu|ee|md|is|my|lv|gt|pk|ni|by|ae|kr|su|vn|cy|am|ke))))))(?!(((ttp|tp|ttps):\\/\\/)|(ww\\.)|(n--)))"
```

Above solves just about everything except a string like "eurls:www.google.com,facebook.com,http://test.com/", which it returns as a single string. Tbh idk why I added gopher etc.
Proof R code

```
if(T){
  wierdurl<-vector()
  wierdurl[1]<-"https://JP納豆.例.jp/dir1/納豆 "
  wierdurl[2]<-"xn--jp-cd2fp15c.xn--fsq.jp "
  wierdurl[3]<-"http://52.221.161.242/2018/11/23/biofourmis-collab"
  wierdurl[4]<-"https://12000.org/ "
  wierdurl[5]<-"  https://vg-1.com/?page_id=1002 "
  wierdurl[6]<-"https://3dnews.ru/822878"
  wierdurl[7]<-"The link of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string
  Also there are some urls: www.google.com, facebook.com, http://test.com/method?param=wasd
  The code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list. "
  wierdurl[8]<-"Thelinkofthisquestion:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string
  Alsotherearesomeurls:www.google.com,facebook.com,http://test.com/method?param=wasd
  Thecodebelowcatchesallurlsintextandreturnsurlsinlist. "
  wierdurl[9]<-"Thelinkofthisquestion:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-stringAlsotherearesomeurlsZwww.google.com,facebook.com,http://test.com/method?param=wasdThecodebelowcatchesallurlsintextandreturnsurlsinlist."
  wierdurl[10]<-"1facebook.com/1res"
  wierdurl[11]<-"1facebook.com/1res/wat.txt"
  wierdurl[12]<-"www.e "
  wierdurl[13]<-"is this the file.txt i need"
  wierdurl[14]<-"xn--jp-cd2fp15c.xn--fsq.jpinspiredby "
  wierdurl[15]<-"[xn--jp-cd2fp15c.xn--fsq.jp/inspiredby "
  wierdurl[16]<-"xnto--jpto-cd2fp15c.xnto--fsq.jpinspiredby "
  wierdurl[17]<-"fsety--fwdvg-gertu56.ffuoiw--ffwsx.3dinspiredby "
  wierdurl[18]<-"://3dnews.ru/822878 "
  wierdurl[19]<-" http://mywebsite.com/msn.co.uk "
  wierdurl[20]<-" 2.0http://www.abe.hip "
  wierdurl[21]<-"www.abe.hip"
  wierdurl[22]<-"hardware/software/data"
  regexstring<-vector()
  regexstring[2]<-"(http|ftp|https)://([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"
  regexstring[3]<-"/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/|www\\.|ftp\\.)(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$])/igm"
  regexstring[4]<-"[a-zA-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]?"
  regexstring[5]<-"((http|ftp|https)\\:\\/\\/)?([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"
  regexstring[6]<-"((http|ftp|https):\\/\\/)?([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?"
  regexstring[7]<-"(http|ftp|https)(:\\/\\/)([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"
  regexstring[8]<-"(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/|www\\.|ftp\\.)(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])"
  regexstring[10]<-"((http[s]?|ftp):\\/)?\\/?([^:\\/\\s]+)((\\/\\w+)*\\/)([\\w\\-\\.]+[^#?\\s]+)(.*)?(#[\\w\\-]+)?"
  regexstring[12]<-"http[s:/]+[[:alnum:]./]+"
  regexstring[9]<-"http[s:/]+[[:alnum:]./]+" #in DLpages 230
  regexstring[1]<-"[[:alnum:]-]+?[.][:alnum:]+?(?=[/ :])" #in link_graphs 50
  regexstring[13]<-"^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:http|https|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[0-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:(/|\\?|#)[^\\s]*)?$"
  regexstring[14]<-"(((((http|ftp|https):\\/\\/)|(www\\.)|(xn--)){1}([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?)|(([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)*))((\\.((org|com|net|edu|gov|mil|int)|(([:alpha:]{2})(?=[, ]))))|([\\/]([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?))))(?!(((ttp|tp|ttps):\\/\\/)|(ww\\.)|(n--)))"
  regexstring[15]<-"(((((http|ftp|https|gopher|telnet|file|localhost):\\/\\/)|(www\\.)|(xn--)){1}([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?)|(([\\w_-]{2,200}(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)*))((\\.[\\w_-]+\\/([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?)|(\\.((org|com|net|edu|gov|mil|int|arpa|biz|info|unknown|one|ninja|network|host|coop|tech)|(jp|br|it|cn|mx|ar|nl|pl|ru|tr|tw|za|be|uk|eg|es|fi|pt|th|nz|cz|hu|gr|dk|il|sg|uy|lt|ua|ie|ir|ve|kz|ec|rs|sk|py|bg|hk|eu|ee|md|is|my|lv|gt|pk|ni|by|ae|kr|su|vn|cy|am|ke))))))(?!(((ttp|tp|ttps):\\/\\/)|(ww\\.)|(n--)))"
    }

for(i in wierdurl){#c(7,22)
  for(c in regexstring[c(15)]) {
    print(paste(i,which(regexstring==c)))
    print(str_extract_all(i,c))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have utilize c# Uri class and it works, well with IP Address, localhost

```
 public static bool CheckURLIsValid(string url)
    {
        Uri returnURL;

       return (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out returnURL)
           && (returnURL.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || returnURL.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps));


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex is perfectly working for me, should work for you too

```
(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight improvement on/adjustment to (depending on what you need) Rajeev's answer:

```
([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.|\s*\[dot\]\s*[A-Z\-_]+)+))([A-Z\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[A-Z\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#]){2,6}?
```

See [here](http://regexr.com/3a84o) for an example of what it does and does not match.

I got rid of the check for "http" etc as I wanted to catch url's without this. I added slightly to the regex to catch some obfuscated urls (i.e. where user's use [dot] instead of a "."). Finally I replaced "\w" with "A-Z" to and "{2,3}" to reduce false positives like v2.0 and "moo.0dd".

Any improvements on this welcome.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`is really poor for matching TLD, see official list: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt. Also your regex matches `_.........&&&&&&` not sure it's a valid url.

Comment: Thanks for that JE SUIS CHAELIE, any suggestions for improvement (especially for the false positive)?

Answer (score 0):

I use the logic of finding text between two dots or periods

the regex below works fine with python

```
(?<=\.)[^}]*(?=\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching a URL in a text should not be so complex

`(?:(?:(?:ftp|http)[s]*:\/\/|www\.)[^\.]+\.[^ \n]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/wewpP1/2

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
^(https?:\\/\\/([a-zA-z0-9]+)(\\.[a-zA-z0-9]+)(\\.[a-zA-z0-9\\/\\=\\-\\_\\?]+)?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:vnc|s3|ssh|scp|sftp|ftp|http|https)\:\/\/[\w\.]+(?:\:?\d{0,5})|(?:mailto|)\:[\w\.]+\@[\w\.]+
```

If you want an explanation of each part, try in regexr[.]com where you will get a great explanation of every character.

This is split by an "|" or "OR" because not all useable URI have "//" so this is where you can create a list of schemes as or conditions that you would be interested in matching.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
(http:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?
```

It matches both in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This slightly simpler version of GooDeeJAY's answer serves me well (and supports e.g. # and other characters at the expense of increasing 'false positives'):

```
import re
text = """The link of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string
Also there are some urls: www.google.com, facebook.com, http://test.com/method?param=wasd, http://test.com/method?param=wasd&params2=kjhdkjshd#changed
The code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list."""

regex = r"(?i)(https?://|www.|\w+\.)[^\s]+"
urls = [match.group() for match in re.finditer(regex, text)]
print(urls)
```

and outputs

```
[
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string', 
'www.google.com,', 
'facebook.com,', 
'http://test.com/method?param=wasd,', 
'http://test.com/method?param=wasd&params2=kjhdkjshd#changed'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression also finds paths like: /path/text.html

```
(https?\:\/[^\"\'\n\<\>\;\)\s]*)|(www?\.[^\"\'\n\<\>\;\s]*)|([^\s\&\=\;\,\<\<\>\"\'\(\)]+\/[\w\/])([^\"\'\n\;\s]*)|((?<!\<)[\/]+[\w]+[^\'\"\s\<\>]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex catches even domains like `goo.gl` or `domains.google`.

```
/(?:(?:((http|ftp|https):){0,1}\/\/)|www.|)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)*))(\.(aaa|aarp|abarth|abb|abbott|abbvie|abc|able|abogado|abudhabi|ac|academy|accenture|accountant|accountants|aco|active|actor|ad|adac|ads|adult|ae|aeg|aero|aetna|af|afamilycompany|afl|africa|ag|agakhan|agency|ai|aig|aigo|airbus|airforce|airtel|akdn|al|alfaromeo|alibaba|alipay|allfinanz|allstate|ally|alsace|alstom|am|amazon|americanexpress|americanfamily|amex|amfam|amica|amsterdam|an|analytics|android|anquan|anz|ao|aol|apartments|app|apple|aq|aquarelle|ar|arab|aramco|archi|army|arpa|art|arte|as|asda|asia|associates|at|athleta|attorney|au|auction|audi|audible|audio|auspost|author|auto|autos|avianca|aw|aws|ax|axa|az|azure|ba|baby|baidu|banamex|bananarepublic|band|bank|bar|barcelona|barclaycard|barclays|barefoot|bargains|baseball|basketball|bauhaus|bayern|bb|bbc|bbt|bbva|bcg|bcn|bd|be|beats|beauty|beer|bentley|berlin|best|bestbuy|bet|bf|bg|bh|bharti|bi|bible|bid|bike|bing|bingo|bio|biz|bj|bl|black|blackfriday|blanco|blockbuster|blog|bloomberg|blue|bm|bms|bmw|bn|bnl|bnpparibas|bo|boats|boehringer|bofa|bom|bond|boo|book|booking|boots|bosch|bostik|boston|bot|boutique|box|bq|br|bradesco|bridgestone|broadway|broker|brother|brussels|bs|bt|budapest|bugatti|build|builders|business|buy|buzz|bv|bw|by|bz|bzh|ca|cab|cafe|cal|call|calvinklein|cam|camera|camp|cancerresearch|canon|capetown|capital|capitalone|car|caravan|cards|care|career|careers|cars|cartier|casa|case|caseih|cash|casino|cat|catering|catholic|cba|cbn|cbre|cbs|cc|cd|ceb|center|ceo|cern|cf|cfa|cfd|cg|ch|chanel|channel|charity|chase|chat|cheap|chintai|chloe|christmas|chrome|chrysler|church|ci|cipriani|circle|cisco|citadel|citi|citic|city|cityeats|ck|cl|claims|cleaning|click|clinic|clinique|clothing|cloud|club|clubmed|cm|cn|co|coach|codes|coffee|college|cologne|com|comcast|commbank|community|company|compare|computer|comsec|condos|construction|consulting|contact|contractors|cooking|cookingchannel|cool|coop|corsica|country|coupon|coupons|courses|cpa|cr|credit|creditcard|creditunion|cricket|crown|crs|cruise|cruises|csc|cu|cuisinella|cv|cw|cx|cy|cymru|cyou|cz|dabur|dad|dance|data|date|dating|datsun|day|dclk|dds|de|deal|dealer|deals|degree|delivery|dell|deloitte|delta|democrat|dental|dentist|desi|design|dev|dhl|diamonds|diet|digital|direct|directory|discount|discover|dish|diy|dj|dk|dm|dnp|do|docs|doctor|dodge|dog|doha|domains|doosan|dot|download|drive|dtv|dubai|duck|dunlop|duns|dupont|durban|dvag|dvr|dz|earth|eat|ec|eco|edeka|edu|education|ee|eg|eh|email|emerck|energy|engineer|engineering|enterprises|epost|epson|equipment|er|ericsson|erni|es|esq|estate|esurance|et|etisalat|eu|eurovision|eus|events|everbank|exchange|expert|exposed|express|extraspace|fage|fail|fairwinds|faith|family|fan|fans|farm|farmers|fashion|fast|fedex|feedback|ferrari|ferrero|fi|fiat|fidelity|fido|film|final|finance|financial|fire|firestone|firmdale|fish|fishing|fit|fitness|fj|fk|flickr|flights|flir|florist|flowers|flsmidth|fly|fm|fo|foo|food|foodnetwork|football|ford|forex|forsale|forum|foundation|fox|fr|free|fresenius|frl|frogans|frontdoor|frontier|ftr|fujitsu|fujixerox|fun|fund|furniture|futbol|fyi|ga|gal|gallery|gallo|gallup|game|games|gap|garden|gay|gb|gbiz|gd|gdn|ge|gea|gent|genting|george|gf|gg|ggee|gh|gi|gift|gifts|gives|giving|gl|glade|glass|gle|global|globo|gm|gmail|gmbh|gmo|gmx|gn|godaddy|gold|goldpoint|golf|goo|goodhands|goodyear|goog|google|gop|got|gov|gp|gq|gr|grainger|graphics|gratis|green|gripe|grocery|group|gs|gt|gu|guardian|gucci|guge|guide|guitars|guru|gw|gy|hair|hamburg|hangout|haus|hbo|hdfc|hdfcbank|health|healthcare|help|helsinki|here|hermes|hgtv|hiphop|hisamitsu|hitachi|hiv|hk|hkt|hm|hn|hockey|holdings|holiday|homedepot|homegoods|homes|homesense|honda|honeywell|horse|hospital|host|hosting|hot|hoteles|hotels|hotmail|house|how|hr|hsbc|ht|htc|hu|hughes|hyatt|hyundai|ibm|icbc|ice|icu|id|ie|ieee|ifm|iinet|ikano|il|im|imamat|imdb|immo|immobilien|in|inc|industries|infiniti|info|ing|ink|institute|insurance|insure|int|intel|international|intuit|investments|io|ipiranga|iq|ir|irish|is|iselect|ismaili|ist|istanbul|it|itau|itv|iveco|iwc|jaguar|java|jcb|jcp|je|jeep|jetzt|jewelry|jio|jlc|jll|jm|jmp|jnj|jo|jobs|joburg|jot|joy|jp|jpmorgan|jprs|juegos|juniper|kaufen|kddi|ke|kerryhotels|kerrylogistics|kerryproperties|kfh|kg|kh|ki|kia|kim|kinder|kindle|kitchen|kiwi|km|kn|koeln|komatsu|kosher|kp|kpmg|kpn|kr|krd|kred|kuokgroup|kw|ky|kyoto|kz|la|lacaixa|ladbrokes|lamborghini|lamer|lancaster|lancia|lancome|land|landrover|lanxess|lasalle|lat|latino|latrobe|law|lawyer|lb|lc|lds|lease|leclerc|lefrak|legal|lego|lexus|lgbt|li|liaison|lidl|life|lifeinsurance|lifestyle|lighting|like|lilly|limited|limo|lincoln|linde|link|lipsy|live|living|lixil|lk|llc|llp|loan|loans|locker|locus|loft|lol|london|lotte|lotto|love|lpl|lplfinancial|lr|ls|lt|ltd|ltda|lu|lundbeck|lupin|luxe|luxury|lv|ly|ma|macys|madrid|maif|maison|makeup|man|management|mango|map|market|marketing|markets|marriott|marshalls|maserati|mattel|mba|mc|mcd|mcdonalds|mckinsey|md|me|med|media|meet|melbourneand Innovation|meme|memorial|men|menu|meo|merckmsd|metlife|mf|mg|mh|miami|microsoft|mil|mini|mint|mit|mitsubishi|mk|ml|mlb|mls|mm|mma|mn|mo|mobi|mobile|mobily|moda|moe|moi|mom|monash|money|monster|montblanc|mopar|mormon|mortgage|moscow|moto|motorcycles|mov|movie|movistar|mp|mq|mr|ms|msd|mt|mtn|mtpc|mtr|mu|museum|music|mutual|mutuelle|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nab|nadex|nagoya|name|nationwide|natura|navy|nba|nc|ne|nec|net|netbank|netflix|network|neustar|new|newholland|news|next|nextdirect|nexus|nf|nfl|ng|ngo|nhk|ni|nico|nike|nikon|ninja|nissan|nissay|nl|no|nokia|northwesternmutual|norton|now|nowruz|nowtv|np|nr|nra|nrw|ntt|nu|nycTelecommunications|nz|obi|observer|off|office|okinawa|olayan|olayangroup|oldnavy|ollo|om|omega|one|ong|onl|online|onyourside|ooo|open|oracle|orange|org|organic|orientexpress|origins|osaka|otsuka|ott|ovh|pa|page|pamperedchef|panasonic|panerai|paris|pars|partners|parts|party|passagens|pay|pccw|pe|pet|pf|pfizer|pg|ph|pharmacy|phd|philips|phone|photo|photography|photos|physio|piaget|pics|pictet|pictures|pid|pin|ping|pink|pioneer|pizza|pk|pl|place|play|playstation|plumbing|plus|pm|pn|pnc|pohl|poker|politie|porn|post|pr|pramerica|praxi|press|prime|pro|prod|productions|prof|progressive|promo|properties|property|protection|pru|prudential|ps|pt|pub|pw|pwc|py|qa|qpon|quebec|quest|qvc|racing|radio|raid|re|read|realestate|realtor|realty|recipes|red|redstone|redumbrella|rehab|reise|reisen|reit|reliance|ren|rent|rentals|repair|report|republican|rest|restaurant|review|reviews|rexroth|rich|richardli|ricoh|rightathome|ril|rio|rip|rmit|ro|rocher|rocks|rodeo|rogers|room|rs|rsvp|ru|rugby|ruhr|run|rw|rwe|ryukyu|sa|saarland|safe|safety|sakura|sale|salon|samsclub|samsung|sandvik|sandvikcoromant|sanofi|sap|sapo|sarl|sas|save|saxo|sb|sbi|sbs|sc|sca|scb|schaeffler|schmidt|scholarships|school|schule|schwarz|science|scjohnson|scor|scot|sd|se|search|seat|secure|security|seek|select|sener|services|ses|seven|sew|sex|sexy|sfr|sg|sh|shangrila|sharp|shaw|shell|shia|shiksha|shoes|shop|shopping|shouji|show|showtime|shriram|si|silk|sina|singles|site|sj|sk|ski|skin|sky|skype|sl|sling|sm|smart|smile|sn|sncf|so|soccer|social|softbank|software|sohu|solar|solutions|song|sony|soy|spa|space|spiegel|sport|spot|spreadbetting|sr|srl|srt|ss|st|stada|staples|star|starhub|statebank|statefarm|statoil|stc|stcgroup|stockholm|storage|store|stream|studio|study|style|su|sucks|supplies|supply|support|surf|surgery|suzuki|sv|swatch|swiftcover|swiss|sx|sy|sydney|symantec|systems|sz|tab|taipei|talk|taobao|target|tatamotors|tatar|tattoo|tax|taxi|tc|tci|td|tdk|team|tech|technology|tel|telecity|telefonica|temasek|tennis|teva|tf|tg|th|thd|theater|theatre|tiaa|tickets|tienda|tiffany|tips|tires|tirol|tj|tjmaxx|tjx|tk|tkmaxx|tl|tm|tmall|tn|to|today|tokyo|tools|top|toray|toshiba|total|tours|town|toyota|toys|tp|tr|trade|trading|training|travel|travelchannel|travelers|travelersinsurance|trust|trv|tt|tube|tui|tunes|tushu|tv|tvs|tw|tz|ua|ubank|ubs|uconnect|ug|uk|um|unicom|university|uno|uol|ups|us|uy|uz|va|vacations|vana|vanguard|vc|ve|vegas|ventures|verisign|versicherung|vet|vg|vi|viajes|video|vig|viking|villas|vin|vip|virgin|visa|vision|vista|vistaprint|viva|vivo|vlaanderen|vn|vodka|volkswagen|volvo|vote|voting|voto|voyage|vu|vuelos|wales|walmart|walter|wang|wanggou|warman|watch|watches|weather|weatherchannel|webcam|weber|website|wed|wedding|weibo|weir|wf|whoswho|wien|wiki|williamhill|win|windows|wine|winners|wme|wolterskluwer|woodside|work|works|world|wow|ws|wtc|wtf|xbox|xerox|xfinity|xihuan|xin|xperia|xxx|xyz|yachts|yahoo|yamaxun|yandex|ye|yodobashi|yoga|yokohama|you|youtube|yt|yun|za|zappos|zara|zero|zip|zippo|zm|zone|zuerich|zw))(?:([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]){0,1})/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/snRz15/1

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?
```

This will verify the url link....

Answer (score -1):

This is the best one.

```
NSString *urlRegex="(http|ftp|https|www|gopher|telnet|file)(://|.)([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)‌​+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?";
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a simplest one. which work for me fine.

```
%(http|ftp|https|www)(://|\.)[A-Za-z0-9-_\.]*(\.)[a-z]*%
```

Answer (score -1):

It is just simple.

Use this pattern: `\b((ftp|https?)://)?([\w-\.]+\.(com|net|org|gov|mil|int|edu|info|me)|(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))(:\d+)?(\/[\w-\/]*(\?\w*(=\w+)*[&\w-=]*)*(#[\w-]+)*)?`

It matches any link contains:

Allowed Protocols: http, https and ftp

Allowed Domains: *.com, *.net, *.org, *.gov, *.mil, *.int, *.edu, *.info and *.me   OR   IP

Allowed Ports: true

Allowed Parameters: true

Allowed Hashes: true

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it can detect any kind of url with any kind of scheme and yes its tested , while copying remember that there should not be blank psace or a new line character

```
(?:http://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*))*)(?:\?(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*))?)?)|(?:ftp://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*)(?::(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*))?@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*))*)(?:;type=[AIDaid])?)?)|(?:news:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;/?:&=])+@(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3})))|(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|[_.+-])*)|\*))|(?:nntp://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)/(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|[_.+-])*)(?:/(?:\d+))?)|(?:telnet://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*)(?::(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*))?@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))/?)|(?:gopher://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:/(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)(?:%09(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*)(?:%09(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))?)?)?)?)|(?:wais://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)(?:(?:/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))|\?(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*))?)|(?:mailto:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))|(?:file://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))|localhost)?/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*))*))|(?:prospero://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*))*)(?:(?:;(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&])*)=(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&])*)))*)|(?:ldap://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))?/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))(?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)\+(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)))*)(?:(?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:[;,])(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))(?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)\+(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)))*))*(?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:[;,])(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?)(?:\?(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)(?:,(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))*)?)(?:\?(?:base|one|sub)(?:\?(?:((?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)))?)?)?)|(?:(?:z39\.50[rs])://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)(?:\+(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))*(?:\?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))?)?(?:;esn=(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))?(?:;rs=(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)(?:\+(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))*)?))|(?:cid:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?:@&=])*))|(?:mid:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?:@&=])*))?)|(?:vemmi://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[/?:@&=])*)(?:(?:;(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[/?:@&])*)=(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[/?:@&])*))*))?)|(?:imap://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~])+)(?:(?:;[Aa][Uu][Tt][Hh]=(?:\*|(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~])+))))?)|(?:(?:;[Aa][Uu][Tt][Hh]=(?:\*|(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~])+)))(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~])+))?))@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+)?;[Tt][Yy][Pp][Ee]=(?:[Ll](?:[Ii][Ss][Tt]|[Ss][Uu][Bb])))|(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+)(?:\?(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+))?(?:(?:;[Uu][Ii][Dd][Vv][Aa][Ll][Ii][Dd][Ii][Tt][Yy]=(?:[1-9]\d*)))?)|(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+)(?:(?:;[Uu][Ii][Dd][Vv][Aa][Ll][Ii][Dd][Ii][Tt][Yy]=(?:[1-9]\d*)))?(?:/;[Uu][Ii][Dd]=(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:(?:/;[Ss][Ee][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]=(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+)))?)))?)|(?:nfs:(?:(?://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*))*)?)))?)|(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*))*)?))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*))*)?)))
```