# Python regular expression to get URL

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to get a URL out of a long string and I am unsure how write the regex;

```
$ string = '192.00.00.00 - WWW.WEBSITE.COM GET /random/url/link'
```

I am trying to use the 're.search' function in order to pull out the WWW.WEBSITE.COM only without spaces. I would like it look like this;

```
$ get_site = re.search(regex).group()

$ print get_site

$ WWW.WEBSITE.COM
```

Comment: try this `WWW\.(.*)\.COM`. I am no expert in regex that's why I am commenting. Probably someone else can provide a better non-greedy one ?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Why shouldn't it return the IP address? It's just as valid as a URL.

Comment: hi Vipul, thanks for your input. I actually need a more robust method for this. Not all of my sites will start with WWW or anything like that, BUT they will all be in between a (-) and the (GET)!!

Comment: ip's in my dataset are for the individual user

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string

Comment: @MorganTN If they will all be in ' - ' and ' GET ' and there is no space in URL then you can try this: `' - (.*) GET '`

Comment: @iCodez has a great answer, but just something to note: if you want case insensitive searches, use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag within the re class function call; i.e. `get_site = re.search(regex, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)`

Comment: Use [`apachelog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apachelog/1.0) to parse Apache style logfiles if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: you could use this regex also `r'-\s+([A-Z]{3}\.[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]{3})\s+GET'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> BUT they will all be in between a (-) and the (GET)

That is all the information you need:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '192.00.00.00 - WWW.WEBSITE.COM GET /random/url/link'
>>> re.search('-\s+(.+?)\s+GET', string).group(1)
'WWW.WEBSITE.COM'
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of what the Regex pattern is matching:

```
-      # -
\s+    # One or more spaces
(.+?)  # A capture group for one or more characters
\s+    # One or more spaces
GET    # GET
```

Note too that `.group(1)` gets the text captured by `(.+?)`.  `.group()` would return the entire match:

```
>>> re.search('-\s+(.+?)\s+GET', string).group()
'- WWW.WEBSITE.COM GET'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`WWW\.(.+)\.[A-Z]{2,3}`

```
WWW        #WWW
\.         #dot
(.+)       #one or more arbitrary characters
\.         #dot, again
[A-Z]{2,3} #two or three alphabetic uppercase characters (as there are .eu domain, for example)
```

Comment: That regex won't cover subdomains, IP addresses and tld's longer than 3 such as info.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following regex a while ago for a PHP project, its based on the dedicated RFC so it will cover any valid URL. I remember I tested it extensively too, so it should be reliable.

```
const re_host = '(([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]+|([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})';
const re_port = '(:[0-9]+)?';
const re_path = '([a-z0-9-\._\~\(\)]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+';
const re_query = '(\?(([a-z0-9-\._\~!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=:@/\?]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?)?';
const re_frag = '(#(([a-z0-9-\._\~!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=:@/\?]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?)?';
const re_localpart = '[a-z0-9!#\$%&\'*\+-/=\?\^_`{|}\~\.]+';
const re_GraphicFileExts = '\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)';

$this->re_href = '~^'.'('.'https?://'.self::re_host.self::re_port.'|)'.'((/'.self::re_path.')*|/?)'.'/?'.self::re_query.self::re_frag.'$~i';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex also.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '192.00.00.00 - WWW.WEBSITE.COM GET /random/url/link'
>>> match = re.search(r'-\s+([^ ]+)\s+GET', string)
>>> match.group(1)
'WWW.WEBSITE.COM'
```

Breakdown of regex:

```
-        # a literal -
\s+      # one or more spaces
([^ ]+)  # Matches not of space character one or more times and () helps to store the captured characters into a group. 
\s+      # one or more spaces
GET      # All the above must followed the string GET
```