# javascript extract src from string

Tags: javascript

How do I extract the image src from this string by pattern matching?

```
var str = "<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/20.gif\"/><br />\n<b>
    Current Conditions:</b><br />\nFog, 16 C<BR />\n<BR /><b>";
```

?

Comment: what part of the url do you want?

Comment: Why not using jQuery?

Comment: @StefanKoenen Why using jQuery?!

Comment: @StefanKoenen - because including a whole library to handle one simple task is unnecessary overkill?

Comment: Are those backslashes present in your actual string? Where are you getting this string from, exactly?

Comment: That is a string not an image tag!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are in JavaScript, you have a DOM parser readily available. Use it.

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = str;
var img = tmp.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var src = img.src;
```

Done ^_^

Comment: Not enough jQuery or regex.

Comment: @nnnnnn I know, right? I totally suck at this.

Comment: In reality I actually like and use jQuery core (I prefer to implement my own plugins so that I'm in control of their behaviour), but as per my other comments I wouldn't introduce jQuery to a site just for this. I like regex, too, but don't use it on html.

Comment: Best to use `DOMParser` instead. `innerHTML` creates an element and permits execution of arbitrary code if the input string is untrustworthy

Answer (score 1):

A working example to use regular expressions:

```
<script>
    var str = "<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/20.gif\"/><br />\n<b>";
    var regex = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/
    var url = str.match(regex)[0];
    alert(url);
</script>
```

Used the regex string from here: [Regular expression to find URLs within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Comment: The pony he comes... HE COMES... The center cannot hold it is too late he comes...

Comment: I still think it is not fair to downvote a working answer just because it's regex. Refusing to upvote would be enough...

Comment: Isn't that regex overcomplicated for this problem? OP wants whatever is in the src, so no need to match a URL specifically: just match any non-quote characters through to the closing quote.

Comment: Sure, it's a nuke cannon for that issue. You can also use the simple way for matching: /src=\"(.*)\"/ which gives two returns. First with the src tag embraced, the second one is the raw url.

Answer (score -1):

It has to be by pattern matching?
With jquery:

```
var src = $('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: No [tag:jquery] tag, no jQuery answer. Got it?

Comment: With or without a library to help, the question is asking about extracting the src from a *string,* not from an element in the DOM.

Answer (score -2):

You should consider using jquery for that. If you have you html on a string, then just do

```
$('<div>' + myHtml + '</div>').find('img').attr('src');
```

To parse it. If you are not using jquery, you could try something like:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(myHtml, "text/html");
```

With plain js to get the dom.

Comment: Because, of course, you couldn't *possibly* do that with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Normally every website already loads jquery, so you are able to use a cleaner and more powerful syntax. But of course you could do it natively as well.

Comment: *Every* website? Um...no. jQuery doesn't give you a cleaner syntax, because it's still just Javascript using Javascript syntax.

Comment: "*Every website already loads jquery*" Only if the developer decides to...

Comment: My website will not touch jQuery with a fifty foot pole. That way, when my code breaks, I can't blame it on jQuery. Anyone tried submitting a form with `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />` with jQuery validation?

Comment: I only mentioned because op could not know it was possible to parse html strings with jquery. I myself didn't know when I started using it - therefore he wouldn't tag as jquery, because he would think it is irrelevant. And I said 'normally every website uses jquery', of course it is not all of them, and there are several reasons not to, but it is still the majority of them :)