# Extracting for URL from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the first valid URL in a string, which can be anywhere between characters and whitespace

I have tried with the following

```
...
urlRegex: /^(http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/[a-zA-Z-_]+.*)$/,

...
var input = event.target.value // <--- some string;
var url   = input.match(this.urlRegex);
```

Problem is `url` returns the whole string when it finds a url, instead of returning just the part of the string matching the regex

Example
The string

`https://medium.com/aspen-ideas/there-s-no-blueprint-26f6a2fbb99c random stuff sd`

returns

```
["https://medium.com/aspen-ideas/there-s-no-blueprint-26f6a2fbb99c random stuff sd", "https://medium.com/aspen-ideas/there-s-no-blueprint-26f6a2fbb99c random stuff sd", index: 0, input: "https://medium.com/aspen-ideas/there-s-no-blueprint-26f6a2fbb99c random stuff sd"]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: what about not http(s)://  urls ? ftp:// etc ?

Comment: can URL contains all type of characters along with special characters?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/6038061/1066234

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your **`regex`** is incorrect.

**Correct regex for extracting URl :** `/(https?:\/\/[^ ]*)/`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/8uzamdg9/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^ ]*)/;

var input = "https://medium.com/aspen-ideas/there-s-no-blueprint-26f6a2fbb99c random stuff sd";
var url = input.match(urlRegex)[1];
alert(url);
```

Comment: no that only returns the part of the url after the `/`, and only the first segment. I want the whole URL

Comment: That's because you made wrong. Make group like this... `/^(http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/[a-zA-Z-_]+.*)$/`

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it.

Comment: This also matches the next line when the URL is at the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 3):

- You haven't included digits in your regex as part of URL.
- Assuming URL starts from the beginning of the string

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/#javascript) with regex explanation on left side.

[Regex explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28https%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B%28%5C%2F%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B%29%2B%29)

```js
var regex = /^(https?:\/\/[^/]+(\/[\w-]+)+)/;
var str = 'https://medium.com/aspen-ideas/there-s-no-blueprint-26f6a2fbb99c random stuff sd';

var url = str.match(regex)[0];
document.write(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because the match result holds the whole string first that matches, then the groups. I guess you want the group, so you can do this:

```
url[1]
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgt8u6pc/1/

```js
var urlRegex = /^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([a-zA-Z-_]+).*$/;
var input = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760030/extracting-for-url-from-string-using-regex' // <--- some string;
var url = input.match(urlRegex);

$('#one').text(url[0]);
$('#two').text(url[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```