# RegEx for finding URLs inside a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
<h1>hello/h1>
<script src="http://www.test.com/file1.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.test.com/file2.js"></script>
<p>bye</p>
```

and I need to generate an array with the urls found in the string.

```
['http://www.test.com/file1.js', 'http://www.test.com/file2.js']
```

also I need to replace the entire line (including the tags script tags) with nothing.

this is what I have so far to find the urls

```
^(<script src=")(.*)("><\/script>)$
```

problem with that is that it only works with

```
<script src="http://www.test.com/file1.js"></script>
```

if I define my scripts like this

```
<script id="something" src="http://www.test.com/file1.js"></script>
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3478852

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting for URL from string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760030/extracting-for-url-from-string-using-regex)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a proper HTML parser instead, like cheerio: find `<script>` tags, remove them, and push their `src` to an array:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const htmlStr = `<h1>hello/h1>
<script src="http://www.test.com/file1.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.test.com/file2.js"></script>
<p>bye</p>`;
const $ = cheerio.load(htmlStr);

const urls = [];
$('script').each((_, script) => {
  urls.push(script.src);
  $(script).remove();
});
const result = $('body').html();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the urls only you can do:

```
^<script.*?src="(.*)".*?><\/script>$
```

This catches cases where attributes are before AND after the `src` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/d8lzqx/1/) might help you to get those URLs:

```
^<.+="(.+)"><\/.+>$
```

It creates a single group, where your target URLs are and filters everything else. It also works with `<a>` tags and other similar tags with open and close patterns.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use this insted

```
^(<script )(.*)(src=")(.*)("><\/script>)$
```

and the 4th groups are the urls

or `^(?:<script )(?:.*)(?:src=")(.*)(?:"><\/script>)$` to use non - capturing groups.