# how to Extract Link part from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Having a string of the below structure how can i extract only the link portion of it.
https://qr.1688.com/s/OaPpTrzR CZ0736

https://qr.1688.com/s/2Q8NXya1 CZ3050

```
const getShortUrl = (string)  =>{
    let query = string.trim().replaceAll('"', '');
    if(query.indexOf('https://qr') >= 0){
          return query.substring(query.indexOf('https://qr'));
        
    }
  }


But the above code return something like `https://qr.1688.com/s/2Q8NXya1 CZ3050` but what i wanted is something like this `https://qr.1688.com/s/2Q8NXya1`

how can i extrract this portion of string.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting for URL from string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760030/extracting-for-url-from-string-using-regex)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211233/how-to-detect-and-get-url-on-string-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **split**:

```
return query.split(' ')?.[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string into parts by the space with the `.split(" ")` method. And then just use the first element of the created array.

### Example

```
query = query.split(" ")[0]
```

### With your code

```js
const getShortUrl = (string) => {
  let query = string.trim().replaceAll('"', '');
  query = query.split(" ")[0]
  if (query.indexOf('https://qr') >= 0) {
    return query.substring(query.indexOf('https://qr'));

  }
}

const shortUrl = getShortUrl("https://qr.1688.com/s/OaPpTrzR CZ0736")
console.log(shortUrl)
```