# How to detect url in JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube, youtube-api

I am retrieving YouTube video description from the below link, but how do I detect the url in the description of video and put that url in anchor tag.

> Possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

URL:- https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=XL9Ri8pO68w&part=snippet&key=AIzaSyDwvYPAjxKcrcnU_fOZxHl3YSfdTA7fVl0

Comment: you can check the `indexOf` `http:://` or `https://` in the description and extract the same.

Comment: @gurvinder372 nope. OP should parse the JSON and obtain the description field.

Comment: Can you share how the description look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to find URLs within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Comment: @Raptor he has already parsed the JSON and obtained description field. Now he needs to extract the URL out of it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery .getJSON() function:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=XL9Ri8pO68w&part=snippet&key=AIzaSyDwvYPAjxKcrcnU_fOZxHl3YSfdTA7fVl0', function(data) {
//data is the JSON string
});
```

Comment: OP is asking how to obtain the description field from the JSON response.

Comment: I am getting description but how to detect the anchor link in the description and show it in Anchor tag on my page.

Comment: @InderjeetSinghAhuja you'll need to use RegEx.