# how to remove all text except image links

Tags: html

I have a text file that contains a lot of html tags,a lot of text and some http image links like http://dsabhbadfbsafasd.com/daifds.jpg
how do I remove all text and tags so only the image links are left? 
or how to get all the links out from the text. 
is there a software or website that can do this ？
thanks

Comment: Your solution is Regex !
[link about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you building a webpage, and you want to take away links? Are you trying to copy and paste into a word document and you want the links to be removed? Do you want to get a list of all links on your webpage? Please give an example of what you want your output to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an online app that can extract the src strings but it might not get all the images. Something like this site.

https://www.piliapp.com/generator/get-img-src/