# Dataframe slicing from cell after reading csv

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, series

I am reading data from Twitter analytics with CSV and DataFrames.

I want to **extract url from certain cell**

The output is this process is the following

```
tweet number tweet id               tweet link              tweet text
1            1.0086341313026E+018   "tweet link goes here"  tweet text goes here https://example.com"
```

How can I slice this "tweet text" to get the url of it? I cannot slice it using [-1:-12] because there are many tweets with different characters number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you want:

```
print (df['tweet text'].str[-12:-1])
0    example.com
Name: tweet text, dtype: object
```

More general solution is with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37807990/2901002) with [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for list of all links and if necessary select first by indexing with `str[0]`:

```
pat = r'(?:http|ftp|https)://(?:[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?'

print (df['tweet text'].str.findall(pat).str[0])
0    https://example.com
Name: tweet text, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way which uses a list of strings and [`pd.Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for finding a valid URL:

```
s = pd.Series(['tweet text goes here https://example.com',
               'some http://other.com example',
               'www.thirdexample.com is here'])

test_strings = ['http', 'www']

def url_finder(x):
    return next(i for i in x.split() if any(t in i for t in test_strings))

res = s.apply(url_finder)

print(res)

0     https://example.com
1        http://other.com
2    www.thirdexample.com
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that will work if the domain name length is variable, rather than always 11 characters long:

```
In [2]: df['tweet text'].str.split('//').str[-1]

Out[2]:
1    example.com
Name: tweet text, dtype: object
```

Comment: better is `df['tweet text'].str.split('//').str[-1])`

Comment: Thanks, thought there must have been a better way than apply but couldn't find it, will edit.