# Regular Expression - detect Specific Url and replace that string

Tags: java, android, regex, linkify

I wanna detect exact domain `url` in string and then change that with another string and finally make it clickable in `TextView`.

What I want:

```
this is sample text with one type of url mydomain.com/pin/123456. another type of url is mydomain.com/username.
```

Wel, I wrote this regex:

```
([Hh][tT][tT][pP][sS]?://)?(?:www\\.)?example\\.com/?.*

([Hh][tT][tT][pP][sS]?://)?(?:www\\.)?example\\.com/pin/?.*
```

this regex can detect:

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
Hhtp://www.example.com // and all other wrong type in http
```

with anything after `.com`

Issues:

**1.** How detect end of domain ( with space or dot)

**2.** How detect two type of domain, one with `/pin/` and another without?

**3.** How to replace detected domain like `mydomain.com/pin/123` with `PostLink` and `mydomain.com/username` with `ProfileLink`

**4.** I know how to make them clickable with `Linkify` but if it possible show me best way to provide content provider for links to open each link with proper activity

Comment: so why aren't you using `Linkify`?

Comment: @pskink How? can you provide snippet of code

Comment: `I  know how to make them clickable with Linkify`, if you know so what code do you need?

Comment: @pskink Issue is `regex` not linkify

Comment: do your urls always contain a http/https or is it always like your example?
Also is it always 1 or two 2 slashes or could it also be more?

Comment: @Gildraths urls My regex handle http/https or www  or bad type as prefix in url, but problem is how to detect domain with 1 or two slashes. urls can just have 2 slashes at all no further more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With special thanks of [Gildraths](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3644766/gildraths)

**Answer to question 1**

```
String urlRegex = "(https?://)?(?:www\\.)?exampl.com+([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textString);
```

**Answer to question 2, 3**

```
while(matcher.find()){

    // Answer to question 2 - If was true, url contain "/pin"
    boolean contain = matcher.group().indexOf("/pin/") >= 0;

    if(contain){

        String profileId = matcher.group().substring(matcher.group().indexOf("/pin/") + 5, matcher.group().length());

    }

    // Answer to question 3 - replace match group with custom text
    textString = textString.replace(matcher.group(), "@" + profileId);
}
```

**Answer to question 4**

```
// Pattern to detect replaced custom text
Pattern profileLink     = Pattern.compile("[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");

// Schema
String Link             = "content://"+Context.getString(R.string.profile_authority)+"/";

// Make it linkify ;)
Linkify.addLinks(textView, profileLink, Link);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

which is a regex I found after a quick search here on stackoverflow:
[Regular expression to find URLs within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

I just removed the `http://` part of that regex to fit your needs.

Be aware though that because of that it now tracks everything that is connected with a dot and no whitespace. For example: `a.a` would also be found

Comment: Dude, first i want to detect `specific domain url` not `all url` in string. second after i've found that i wanna to replace them with another string as I said in my question description and finally make clickable it by `Linkify`. thanks for your interest ;)

Comment: @MAY3AM `demo.com+([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?` will give you all the strings matching to the domain demo.com . 
If pin is always at the same position:
`demo.com\/pin+([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?`
I would then compare both results, since regex is not good at excluding results