# How to extract a link from a String in Java or Groovy?

Tags: string, parsing, groovy

Let's say you have this variable,

```
String message = "This is a link http://www.example.com/"
```

or you have this,

```
String message2 = "This is a link http://www.example.com/ and another link http://www.myfico.com/Images/sample_overlay.gif"
```

How can I extract only the link into a list?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work for the two examples you give:

```
def links = message2.findAll(/http:\/\/\S+/)
```

That is, find anything that starts with `http://` up until some sort of whitespace

There are more complex regular expressions [over on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string), but I've not tried any of them, and they may be overkill for your situation