# Regular expressions in Excel macro code not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, and it's not executing due to an error message that reads "Method 'Execute' of object 'IRegExp2 failed"

```
Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Dim pg As Page
Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

For Each wrksht In Worksheets
    For Each pg In wrksht.PageSetup.pages
        With regEx
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = "[(ftp|FTP|http|HTTP|s|S)]{3,5}*[\:/]{3}*[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{2,}[\.]*[.A-Za-z0-9\s]{2,}"
        End With

        If regEx.Execute(pg.CenterFooter.Text) Then
            pg.CenterFooter.Text = regEx.Replace(pg.CenterFooter.Text, "")
        End If
    Next pg
Next wrksht
```

I'm looking to replace the beginning part of URLs (***www.sampleurl.com***/subfolder/testfile.pdf) and keeping only the trailing part (www.sampleurl.com ***/subfolder/testfile.pdf***, minus the space after the .com part)

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing "*.com/" with ""?  Unsure if you've got a set column/row with that info, but you could loop through pages and possibly avoid the regexp2 error.

Comment: Thanks, @Cyril. I could try that, but that would only take care of "*.com/", and I'm expecting other domains ending in ".net", ".org", etc. I need to make this general enough to remove all url roots, and leave the trailing 'path'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the regular expression from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041965/5947891, and the following is a final version that worked for me. Basically, this will scan through all sheets in the workbook, check for url pattern, truncate the URL base (**http ://www.sample.com**/subfolder/subfile.png) and leave the trailing part(s) (e.g., http ://www.sample.com**/subfolder/subfile.png**). I added spaces after http in the URL to invalidate the href.

```
Sub FixFooter()
    Dim oSection As Word.Section
    Dim oRange As Word.Range
    Dim var
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    Dim pg As Page

    Dim regEx As New RegExp 'New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String

    strPattern1 = "(http|ftp|https){0,1}(\://){0,1}([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))/"

    For Each wrksht In Worksheets
        Set pg = wrksht.PageSetup.pages(1)

        With regEx
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .Pattern = strPattern1

        End With

        If regEx.Test(pg.CenterFooter.Text) Then
            pg.CenterFooter.Text = "/" & regEx.Replace(pg.CenterFooter.Text, "")
        End If
    Next wrksht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more generic than replacing the .com (per comments)... Hopefully this gets you where you need to be:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR

    Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), "https://", "", , 1)
    Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), "http://", "", , 1)
    Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), "/", "(error)", , 1)

    Next i

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, 1)).Replace What:="*(error)", Replacement:=""
```

My assumption is there is a column with the addresses in them.

Comment: Thanks again, @Cyril. However, in my initial example, I was focused on modifying the footer.

Comment: Got;cha; sorry about that.  Glad you found your answer (saw you post below).