# Using .find(" ") method without cutting last character if the substring is at the very end

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

I am trying to find a substring which is a basically a link to any website. The idea is that if a user posts something, the link will be extracted and assigned to a variable called web_link. My current code is following:

```
post = ("You should watch this video https://www.example.com if you have free time!")
web_link = post[post.find("http" or "www"):post.find(" ", post.find("http" or "www"))]
```

The code works perfectly if there is a spacebar after the link, however, if the link inside the post is at the very end. For example:

```
post = ("You should definitely watch this video https://www.example.com")
```

Then the `post.find(" ")` can not find a spacebar/whitespace and returns `-1` which results in web_link `"https://www.example.co"`

I am trying to find a solution that does not involve an if statement if possible.

Comment: Side comment: `if` isn't a function.

Comment: you should be using regex otherwise your function won't be very robust... a simple "python extract url from string" google search would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because if the string isn't found and -1 is returned the slice commands interprets this as "the rest of the string -1 character from the end".

As ifma pointed out the best way to achieve this would be with a regular expression. Something like:

```
re.search("(https?://|www[^\s]+)", post).group(0)
```

Comment: This doesn't include web links starting "www". Actually, if you use a string without "https", you'll get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Yes fair enough. Updated to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex. I've made a little change the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041965/6900838).

```
import re

def func(post):
    return re.search("[(http|ftp|https)://]*([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?", post).group(0)

print(func("You should watch this video www.example.com if you have free time!"))
print(func("You should watch this video https://www.example.com"))
```

Output:

```
www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

But I should say, using **"if"** is simpler and obvious:

```
def func(post):
    start = post.find("http" or "www")
    finish = post.find(" ", start)
    return post[start:] if finish == -1 else post[start:finish]
```