# Get img from div element and use it as src for another element

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have a list of articles with a preview feature which does let the user hover the title of the article to have a brief preview of the content, and the structure is as follows:

`<img id="{article_id}" src="" /><a href="/something.html" id="{article_id}" data-original-title="https://website.tld/path/image.jpg some other text here">Name of the Article</a>`

I need to dynamically take the link to the image (in this example "https://website.tld/path/image.jpg" ) of each of my article previews to fill the empty "img src", knowing that:

1. The url of the image is different in each article preview
2. The {article_id} is different in each article

Here's a more comprehensive jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znnytLrf/2/

I was thinking about using a regex to isolate the image url which always appears at the top, which can basically be treat as a word in regex, but I'm getting very confused as I spent my last 48 hours on it without any significant progresses.

How can I achieve this using jquery? If not, or too trivial, do you have some alternative ways to accomplish this?

**Thank you so much for reading my question**.

Comment: If you're already using an HTML5 `data-*` attribute, why not use more. Have a separate one for the URL and a separate one for the text? Then you can reference each as you need them.

Comment: I'm started this question because I've been unable to strip only the img url from the preview feature on my site, or I would have directly pasted it in the src="", so I'm looking for a way to strip the image url and copy it inside the image src.

Comment: Well, if you really really need to use a regex, there are plenty to be found on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)). That first answer would return just the image URL like you want ([example](https://regex101.com/r/RvtDuX/1)).

Comment: Thanks, but in the text there might be some other urls, and that regex would match other urls.

Comment: if the url is always at the start syou can use a regex like `$(.*)\s`

Comment: If the image URL is always the first URL, you could work with that still. If not, are there other image URLs in that string? If there's only a single image URL, and you know what the file types would be, you could change the regex to handle that.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and prompt reply. Assuming I want to proceed with RegEx, how can I grab the url dynamically from each article and place it in each img tag? They both have the {article_id} in my html template, and javascript can't handle html variables, right? Thanks again.

Comment: haave you already jquery code?

Comment: No, I don't have it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the {article_id} multipe times as id for your elements like `id="article232"`.

If you mean by "*the image url which always appears at the top*" that the image url is always at the beginning of the string, you could use a regex like [`(?=^https?)(.+?)\s`](https://regex101.com/r/G1oUBf/1) to take the characters until you encounter a whitespace.

Then in your jQuery, a possible option would be to:

- find all the anchors and loop them
- grab the `data-original-title` attribute and use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to get the value that you are looking for
- then get the previous image element and set it's `src` attribute with the value that you have found

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div p a').each(function () {
        var myRegexp = /(?=^https?)(.+?)\s/g;
        var match = myRegexp.exec($(this).attr("data-original-title"));
        if (match && match[1]) {
            $(this).prev("img").attr("src", match[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtwx8o7u/3/)

Comment: Thank you, it works great in the jsFiddle, but on my live site it's not working, for some reasons. Any ideas? You can find a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtwx8o7u/1/ and the live page is here: https://sbenny.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=12&sk=t&sd=d&start=20

Comment: You're a genius :) Thank you so much

Comment: I applied your changes with some quick-dirty css edits as you can see here: https://sbenny.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=12&sk=t&sd=d&start=20 any ways to make the regex only match the first word which starts with "http|https"? There are some rare occurrences where the image url isn't at the top, but after some words, thanks again. After this I'll mark your answer as the accepted :) I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: I've updated the javascript to only match the first word which starts with "http:https". [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G1oUBf/1)

Comment: Thank you again, you're very very kind and ready to help. Kudos!