# find all links in html parsed beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup with python. In scrapping pages links are not enclosed in `<a href>` tags.

I want to get all links starting with http/https using soup operation. I have tried some regex given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48769624/2286762) but they are giving unexpected results for me. 
so i thought if anything is possible using soup?

Example responses from which i want to get links:

```
<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600" rel="stylesheet"/>\n<style>\n    html, body {\n    height: 100%;\n    width: 100%;\n    }\n\n    body {\n    background: #F5F6F8;\n    font-size: 16px;\n    font-family: \'Open Sans\', sans-serif;\n    color: #2C3E51;\n    }\n    .main {\n    display: flex;\n    align-items: center;\n    justify-content: center;\n    height: 100vh;\n    }\n    .main > div > div,\n    .main > div > span {\n    text-align: center;\n    }\n    .main span {\n    display: block;\n    padding: 80px 0 170px;\n    font-size: 3rem;\n    }\n    .main .app img {\n    width: 400px;\n    }\n  </style>\n<script type="text/javascript">\n      var fallback_url = "null";\n      var store_link = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/GB/app/id1032680895?ls=1&mt=8";\n      var web_store_link = "https://itunes.apple.com/GB/app/id1032680895?mt=8";\n      var loc = window.location;\n      function redirect_to_web_store(loc) {\n        loc.href = web_store_link;\n      }\n      function redirect(loc) {\n        loc.href = store_link;\n        if (fallback_url.startsWith("http")) {\n          setTimeout(function() {\n            loc.href = fallback_url;\n          },5000);\n        }\n      }\n  </script>\n<body onload="redirect(loc)">\n<div class="main">\n<div class="workarea">\n<div class="logo">\n<img onclick="redirect_to_web_store(loc)" src="https://cdnappicons.appsflyer.com/app|id1032680895.png" style="width:200px;height:200px;border-radius:20px;"/>\n</div>\n<span>BetBull: Sports Betting &amp; Tips</span>\n<div class="app">\n<img onclick="redirect_to_web_store(loc)" src="https://cdn.appsflyer.com/af-statics/images/rta/app_store_badge.png"/>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>
```

Tried:

```
regex_pattern_to_find_all_links = r'(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+'
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), 'html.parser')
urls = re.findall(regex_pattern_to_find_all_links, str(soup))
```

Result:

```
['https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open', '//itunes.apple.com/GB/app/id1032680895?ls=1', 'https://itunes.apple.com/GB/app/id1032680895?mt=8', 'window.location', 'loc.href', 'loc.href', 'fallback_url.startsWith', 'loc.href', 'https://cdnappicons.appsflyer.com/app', 'id1032680895.png', 'https://cdn.appsflyer.com/af-statics/images/rta/app_store_badge.png']
```

As you can see above, I am not sure why regex is matching things which are not even urls.

[What I have tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string/47736263#47736263)
Most upvoted and accepted answer here is not able to detect links at all!!
I am not sure what i am doing wrong,

Comment: You made protocol optional. So that's the reason.

Comment: ok how do i make it neccessary?

Comment: As the first part use this instead `(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\bwww\.)`

Comment: See a demo here https://regex101.com/r/Sz7p1M/1

Comment: It seems it worked for you so I posted it as an answer below.

Comment: yes now i am trying to ignore links which have jpg png etc as ending on it.

Comment: See this https://regex101.com/r/hpT01F/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with protocol that you made optional and engine isn't forced to match it if it is satisfied with the rest of patterns. Try this instead:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\bwww\.)[^\s"']+
```

Not bulletproof but much better. It matches strings starting with `https?` or `ftp` or those with no protocols but `www.`

See live [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Sz7p1M/1)