# regex to extract URLs from text - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to detect the `urls` from a text and replace them by wrapping in quotes like below:

```
original text: Hey, it is a url here www.example.com
required text: Hey, it is a url here "www.example.com"
```

`original text` show my input value and `required text` represents the required output. I searched a lot on web but could not find any possible solution. I already have tried `URL.extract` feature but that doesn't seem to detect `URLs` without `http` or `https`. Below are the examples of some of urls I want to deal with. Kindly let me know if you know the solution.

> ANQUETIL-DUPERRON Abraham-Hyacinthe, KIEFFER Jean-Luc, www.hominides.net/html/actualites/outils-preuve-presence-hominides-asie-0422.php,Les Belles lettres, 2001.
>
> https://www.ancient-code.com/indian-archeologists-stumbleacross-ruins-great-forgotten-civilization-mizoram/
>
> www.jstor.org/stable/24084454
>
> www.biorespire.com/2016/03/22/une-nouvelle-villeantique-d%C3%A9couverte-en-inde/
>
> insu.cnrs.fr/terre-solide/terre-et-vie/de-nouvellesdatations-repoussent-l-age-de-l-apparition-d-outils-surle-so
>
> www.cerege.fr/spip.php?page=pageperso&id_user=94

Comment: so is your logic for this any string which has a `domain.root_domain` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder kindly check the updated text. thanks

Comment: Matching any arbitrary URL is not easy, you will certainly get false positives if you want to also match strings like `googl.com`. Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string) for ideas on what pattern suits your scenario best. Once you know what pattern is good to use the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find words who look like urls:

```
str = "ANQUETIL-DUPERRON Abraham-Hyacinthe, KIEFFER Jean-Luc, www.hominides.net/html/actualites/outils-preuve-presence-hominides-asie-0422.php,Les Belles lettres, 2001.\n\nhttps://www.ancient-code.com/indian-archeologists-stumbleacross-ruins-great-forgotten-civilization-mizoram/\n\nwww.jstor.org/stable/24084454\n\nwww.biorespire.com/2016/03/22/une-nouvelle-villeantique-d%C3%A9couverte-en-inde/\n\ninsu.cnrs.fr/terre-solide/terre-et-vie/de-nouvellesdatations-repoussent-l-age-de-l-apparition-d-outils-surle-so\n\nwww.cerege.fr/spip.php?page=pageperso&id_user=94"

str.split.select{|w| w[/(\b+\.\w+)/]}
```

This will give you an array of words which have no spaces and include a one or more `.` characters which MIGHT work for your use case.

```
puts str.split.select{|w| w[/(\b+\.\w+)/]}
www.hominides.net/html/actualites/outils-preuve-presence-hominides-asie-0422.php,
https://www.ancient-code.com/indian-archeologists-stumbleacross-ruins-great-forgotten-civilization-mizoram/
www.jstor.org/stable/24084454
www.biorespire.com/2016/03/22/une-nouvelle-villeantique-d%C3%A9couverte-en-inde/
insu.cnrs.fr/terre-solide/terre-et-vie/de-nouvellesdatations-repoussent-l-age-de-l-apparition-d-outils-surle-so
www.cerege.fr/spip.php?page=pageperso&id_user=94
```

#### Updated

Complete solution to modify your string:

```
str_with_quote = str.clone # make a clone for the `gsub!`

str.split.select{|w| w[/(\b+\.\w+)/]}
   .each{|url| str_with_quote.gsub!(url, '"' + url + '"')}
```

Now your cloned object wraps urls inside double quotes

```
puts str_with_quote
```

Will give you this output

```
ANQUETIL-DUPERRON Abraham-Hyacinthe, KIEFFER Jean-Luc, "www.hominides.net/html/actualites/outils-preuve-presence-hominides-asie-0422.php,Les" Belles lettres, 2001.

"https://www.ancient-code.com/indian-archeologists-stumbleacross-ruins-great-forgotten-civilization-mizoram/"

"www.jstor.org/stable/24084454"

"www.biorespire.com/2016/03/22/une-nouvelle-villeantique-d%C3%A9couverte-en-inde/"

"insu.cnrs.fr/terre-solide/terre-et-vie/de-nouvellesdatations-repoussent-l-age-de-l-apparition-d-outils-surle-so"

"www.cerege.fr/spip.php?page=pageperso&id_user=94"
```

Comment: classic fix. you rocked

Comment: i wish i could give you more than 1 thumbs up

Comment: @ImranNaqvi all good, see updated answer, it's complete solution I think.