# Unable to parse a link from some content

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a link out of some content using `regex`. I've already got success but I had to use `replace()` function and `this` as a flag. The thing is `this` may not always be present there. So, I seek any solution to get the same output without those two things I've mentioned already.

```
import re

content = """
widgetEvCall('handlers.onMenuClicked', event, this, 'http://www.stirwen.be/medias/documents/20181002_carte_octobre-novembre_2018_FR.pdf')
"""
link = re.findall(r'this,\s*([^)]*)',content.strip())[0].replace("'","")
print(link)
```

Output:

```
http://www.stirwen.be/medias/documents/20181002_carte_octobre-novembre_2018_FR.pdf
```

> How can I get the link using pure regex?

Comment: this post about finding url with regex might be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract all chars between single quotes after `this,` and spaces:

```
import re

content = """
widgetEvCall('handlers.onMenuClicked', event, this, 'http://w...content-available-to-author-only...n.be/medias/documents/20181002_carte_octobre-novembre_2018_FR.pdf')
"""
link = ''
m = re.search(r"this,\s*'([^']*)'", content)
if m:
    link = m.group(1)

print(link)
# => http://www.stirwen.be/medias/documents/20181002_carte_octobre-novembre_2018_FR.pdf
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Gv1x2H)

Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LyNwVj/1).

Comment: Yes, it did it @Wiktor Stribiżew. A quick little question- can I not use `(.*)` instead of `([^']*)` as they both do the same thing here? Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU It depends on what the actual rules are and the strings you will use to extract data from. I see that the value needed is inside single quotation marks, and there are no other single quotation marks are expected, so, `[^']*` seems suitable. It is also more efficient than `.*` that matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and after grabbing the whole line starts backtracking, getting to the place before `'` that is later consumed with `'` pattern part.Negated character class is the best choice to grab a substring from `a` to `a` when no other `a` is expected.