# Can't get newest data from DAO unless restart the app

Tags: java, android

I have a project which is a simple memo app. I have a problem with displaying newest data in my `RecyclerView`. I have to restart the app to see new changes every time the user adds a new memo. How may I fix it?

MainActivity (where the `RecyclerView` is)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRepository = new MemoRepository(this);

    initRecyclerView();
    insertDummyData();
}


private void initRecyclerView(){
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mMemoAdapter = new MemoAdapter(mNotes, this);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMemoAdapter);
}


private void insertDummyData(){
    mRepository.getAllMemos().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
            if (mNotes.size() > 0){
                notes.clear();
            }
            if (notes != null){
                mNotes.addAll(notes);
            }
            mMemoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

Repository

```
public class MemoRepository  {

    private MemoDatabase mDatabase;

    public MemoRepository (Context context){
        this.mDatabase = MemoDatabase.getDatabase(context);
    }

    public void insertNewMemo(Note note){
        new InsertMemoAsyncTask(mDatabase.memoInterface()).execute(note);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllMemos(){
       return mDatabase.memoInterface().getAllMemos();
    }
}
```

Dao interface

```
@Dao
public interface MemoInterface {
    @Insert
    void insertMemo(Note... note);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllMemos();
}
```

Activity where user enter the memo content

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.save_memo: {
            //test
            mNote.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());
            mNote.setContent(content.getText().toString());
            mNote.setTimestamp("00 0000");
            mRepository.insertNewMemo(mNote);
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

In **MemoAdapter** class, add a method:

```
public void setViewItems(List<Note> viewItems) {
    this.viewItems = viewItems
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

And update the following method:

```
private void insertDummyData(){
    mRepository.getAllMemos().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
            if (mNotes.size() > 0){
                notes.clear();
            }
            if (notes != null){
                mNotes.addAll(notes);
            }
            mMemoAdapter.setViewItems(mNotes);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Btw. You have to make that method public ^^

Comment: can you please try to explain how you are trying to achieve? you are saving memo in some other activity? and when you move to list activity the newly added is not shown and once you restart the app, the newly added item is shown. Right?

Comment: if that is the case, then i would suggest to call `insertDummyData();` from `onResume` method rather then from `onCreate()`

Comment: Plus one on the comment above.  When list views need to be refreshed, you should always do it in onResume rather than onCreate.  That way, if you go to a new dialog to, say, add a record, then return to the list view, onResume will get called and refill the list.