# How to find if a text contains url string in PHP

Tags: php

I have try to play around with preg_replace, but couldn't come up with a solution that fit all the exceptions

For example:

If the user enters "visit http://somewebsite.com"

(OR)

```
$text = "visit www . somewebsite . com";
```

(OR)

```
$text = "visit w w w dot somewebsite dot c o m";
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to find this code in pages, or trying to eliminate them from spam for example?

Comment: I'm trying to find these unwanted links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to find URLs within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Comment: Spammers will always find ways to bypass whatever someone comes up with. Since you need to detect them but not use them, I would probably go with take the message, remove all spaces, replace dot with .  and then do a check on urls. This will result in false positives for sure, but might keep most of the spam links out.

Comment: yeah got it ! thanks :)