# extract domain name from url javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract domain name from string in 'tweets', how can I avoid to extract double backward slashes from string?
the regular expression I have defined in let url

```js
let tweets = [
  "Thank you to the Academy and the incredible cast & crew of #TheRevenant. #Oscars",
  "@HardingCompSci department needs student volunteers for #HourOfCode https://hourofcode.com/us",
  "Checkout the most comfortable earbud on #Kickstarter and boost your #productivity https://www.kickstarter.com/",
  "Curious to see how #StephenCurry handles injury. http://mashable.com/2016/04/25/steph-curry-knee-injury-cries-cried/"
];


let url = /\/\/.+?\.com?/;

tweets.forEach(function(tweet) {
  console.log(url.exec(tweet));
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to find URLs within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a [Capturing Group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)

> A part of a pattern can be enclosed in parentheses (...). This is called a “capturing group”.
>
> That has two effects:
>
> It allows to get a part of the match as a separate item in the result array.
> If we put a quantifier after the parentheses, it applies to the parentheses as a whole.

In your code you have `let url = /\/\/.+?\.com?/;`

You are only interested in the part following the 2 slashes, so make a capturing group for that by enclosing it in braces: `let url = /\/\/(.+?\.com?)/;`

Then change the code in the loop a bit to get the result from the first capturing group and you end up with:

```js
let tweets = [
  "Thank you to the Academy and the incredible cast & crew of #TheRevenant. #Oscars",
  "@HardingCompSci department needs student volunteers for #HourOfCode https://hourofcode.com/us",
  "Checkout the most comfortable earbud on #Kickstarter and boost your #productivity https://www.kickstarter.com/",
  "Curious to see how #StephenCurry handles injury. http://mashable.com/2016/04/25/steph-curry-knee-injury-cries-cried/"
];


let url = /\/\/(.+?\.com?)/;

tweets.forEach(function(tweet) {
  var match = url.exec(tweet)
  console.log(match && match[1] || match);
});
```

Comment: I used `match && match[1] || match` to match the original code as close as possible. If it was my code, I would write `match && match[1]` and let the first iteration return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Made a quick script for your query, using the [new URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor.

It splits your tweets by words and test them. When an URL is found, the `urls` array is populated.

```js
let tweets = [
       "Thank you to the Academy and the incredible cast & crew of #TheRevenant. #Oscars",
       "@HardingCompSci department needs student volunteers for #HourOfCode https://hourofcode.com/us",
       "Checkout the most comfortable earbud on #Kickstarter and boost your #productivity https://www.kickstarter.com/",
       "Curious to see how #StephenCurry handles injury. http://mashable.com/2016/04/25/steph-curry-knee-injury-cries-cried/"
    ];
 
let urls = []
 
function getURL(me){
  me.split(" ").forEach(function(e){
    try { 
      new URL(e);
      console.log(e + " is a valid URL!")
      urls.push(e)
    } 
    catch (error){
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  })

}

tweets.forEach(function(tweet){
  getURL(tweet)
})

url.innerHTML = urls.join("<br>")
```

```html
<div id="url"></div>
```