# react replace URLs with a tags

Tags: reactjs

I have a Text component that takes a string prop. The string prop is just sentences which may or may not contain URLs. How can the Text component return a p tag containing the string prop with the URLs replaced with a tags?

So `<Text str="go to example.com" />` shoudl return `<p>go to <a target="blank" href="https://example.com">example.com</a></p>`

I think I have to do a regex match for URLs in the string prop, replace those substrings with a tags, and put that string prop right `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={here} />`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: could you also show us the format of the returned string for URL and normal text ?

Comment: I checked with the regex that could help you with fetching the domain but the issue is, the domain will need to be a proper form or URL something like this `https://example.com`.
this is the regex `/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm`  and the link for the reference is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Comment: I am trying to make something similar to Twitter's tweet input. It highlights URLs without the https://

Comment: you mean something like this [LINK](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/c9fc09782efe59af4ee82855768cfaf36273e170/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly,
You can use simple regex to parse html:

```js
const TextComponent = ({ stringProp }) => {
  const parsed = stringProp.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
  return <p>{parsed}</P>
}
```

Comment: I've added an example to the question description.

Comment: The solution should add `a` tags to the string, not remove them. Please review the question again.