# how can i get a url with form parameters from a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For example i have a string `hello check this out https://example.com?myparam=asd it is cool right?`

and I want to get the `https://example.com?myparam=asd` part but the `?myparam=asd` part can change like `?myparam=newerthing`

Sorry if its a bit messy, I don't know how to describe it better.

Comment: You need to try to explain this in more detail. As it currently stands it is not very clear what your higher level objective is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your text through a regular expression that captures URL patterns. I just went with a popular one. There are a ton of URL patterns floating around on the web.

For each match, you can pass it to the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor which then gets passed to an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). Once you have the `URL` object, you can obtain information about the it such as `origin` and `searchParams`. The `searchParams` object should already be a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)  object, so you can take the `entries()` and pass them to `Object.fromEntries` to get a key-value pair object.

This is rudimentary at best, but it's a start.

```js
// Via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288898/1762224
const URL_REGEX = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm;

const extractUrls = text => text.match(URL_REGEX).map(matched => (url => ({
  url: url,
  origin: url.origin,
  searchParams: Object.fromEntries(url.searchParams.entries())
}))(new URL(matched)));

const urls = extractUrls("hello check this out https://example.com?myparam=asd it is cool right");

console.log(urls);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

You'll able to parse and get params keys and values.

Quick example:

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams   = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

urlParams.get('myparam')
```

Answer (score 0):

I need more details, but maybe u need somethinng like this

```js
const str = 'hello check this out https://example.com?myparam=asd it is cool right?'

const regExUrl = /(myparam=)[^ \&]+/
console.log(str.replace(regExUrl, '$1' + 'neverthing'))
```