# Parse URL from a gibberish string (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js

I have been looking for a way to parse URL from a string.
My current goal is to parse

> https://example.com/foo.png

from a string like

> abcxyz https://example.com/foo.png gibberfish text.

Anyone got a solution or a package that can help me to do the job?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string

Comment: @Molda thanks sir, your answer solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this solution. It turns all words into an array and picks out the ones starting with https://

```
text.split(" ").filter(i => i.startsWith("https://")).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "abcxyz https://example.com/foo.png gibberfish text."
console.log(text.split(" ")[1])
```

`.split()` splits the string at spaces into an array of words.

You can refer: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp