# Issue with an url validation in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, url

I'm trying to validate an url, basically this will be for a project where any kind of weird url could be possibly be introduced by the user, like for example:

- pickup.calendar.com/schedu/e-mail/pickup.php/123wec/99245t29-03882-4ttr-345nvnwikg3545/?
- mypage-services.info
- https://google.com
- http://mypersonaldomain.com.org
- mypersonaldomain2.com.org/services/123
- https%3A%2F%2Mycoolstuff.com
- wikipedia.org
- [www.github.com](http://www.github.com)
- https://testing.com/@myurl/about

I have tried using new URI(url) from java.net but it's not validating correctly, for values like +1.1234566 or just a number 123337000 or a word test it returns true but it shouldn't.

I have also tried the UrlValidator from apache-commons but an url like mypage-services.info says it's invalid.

Last thing i've tried is to use regex, this is what i've got so far:

```
^(http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$\n
```

But it's not working for url patterns like mypage-services.info

I know this seems already like a duplicate question but i have tried all of the regex i have found in similar questions and none of them have worked for my requirement.

To anybody who can provide me help on this i would appreciate it a lot, thank you.

Comment: This post, has a bunch of regular expressions you might be able to use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string/41242257

Full disclosure: One of the answers is mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to find URLs within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all of your examples, you are not actually validating URLs. The referenced Apache Commons [URLValidator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) validates all of the above correctly.

URLs require [by RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) to start with a "scheme", for example `https://` or `mailto:`. When you enter `wikipedia.org` into your browser's address bar, it uses heuristics to best guess what you mean by that: the valid URL `https://wikipedia.org`. All of your examples can be best-guessed this way - by prepending `https://` - except for `https%3A%2F%2Mycoolstuff.com`. That's a tougher case, because percent-encoding is not allowed in the scheme-part of an URL - But as such, it makes for a good example of how quick the guesswork gets ugly.

I'm not aware of a common library for that - probably there isn't one, because there is no universally correct way and it will at some point imply subjective decisions.

[Here's how Firefox does it](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/urlbar/UrlbarTokenizer.sys.mjs). It's a lot of code and it says up front in comment (emphasis mine):

> Regex used to guess url-like strings. These are not expected to be
> 100% correct, we accept some user mistypes and **we're unlikely to be
> able to cover 100% of the cases**.

Comment: This gives more clarity on the matter, thank you for your help.