# How to extract a url from form action using REGEX?

Tags: regex

I have the following url in form action for eaxmple,

```
<form action="https://example.apps.com">
```

How do I fetch just the url 'https://example.apps.com'?

I tried something like this in https://regexr.com/

```
(https:\/\/example.\\*.+)
```

With above, I'm able to skip the first double quote("), but it's still fetching the last double quote(") and angle bracket(>). How do i skip last double quote and angle bracket?

Comment: Something along `https?://[^\s"]+` See https://regex101.com/r/lWlX3I/1

Comment: Do you really have to use regex? Why not a parser?

Comment: This can be as simple as this `action="(.+?)"`, the first group will have your url.

Comment: @luiscla27 Somewhat better would be `action="([^"]+)"`

Comment: you should be able to get any kind of URLs by using this [regex already answered in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041965/12257219)