# URL parsing in PHP

Tags: php, url

Do any PHP parsers exist that get all urls out of a string? I'd like an alternative to regex for getting **all** urls out of a string.

**Update:**

```
    $urls = "http://stackoverflow.com/question
             http://stackoverflow.com/questions";

    //no space between urls
    $urls = "http://stackoverflow.com/questionshttp://stackoverflow.com/questiond";
```

Comment: Any code that is going to pull URL's from a string is going to use RegEx.

Comment: if you need to get from html content then you can use html parsing, let me know if you would like to know

Comment: can you give an example of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no very-easy alternative to regex. But It has been solved using regex already, see [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php) and [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url) .

Regex is quite useful though. Perl and Javascript and Java, etc etc