# Remove URLs from text string

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to search for and remove URLs from a string in PHP. Talking about the actual text here not the HTML. Example to remove:

```
mywebsite.com
http://mywebsite.org
www.mywebsite.co.uk
www.my-web-site.net
sub.mywebsite.edu
etc
```

My issue is users submitting a description field and using it promote their own URLs. I'm not sure if its possible without generating too many false positives. I've thought about detecting the http:// or www. but that doesn't stop links like mywebsite.com

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php. This link may not solve your problem, but there's some information in the answers you may find useful.

Comment: The most effective way to find URLs (whether encoded as www dot place dot com or any other way) is to use the human eyes and brain - involve the community, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something that looks for .TLD, where TLD is any existing top-level domain, but that may result in too many false positives.

Would it be possible to implement a system where posts containing questionable content need moderation to be posted, but others are posted right away? I'm assuming it's a firm business requirement to disallow this type of content.

Personally, I would tend to just prevent any hyperlinking, and leave it at that. But, it's not my app.

Comment: I'd do this - but expand on it a little bit so after I've found a matching TLD I'd go backwards in the string a little bit and inspect the string up until I get a non-url character (like space, newline, etc.). Though this doesn't stop people doing the things where they do "example [dot] c0m"

Comment: Hyperlinking is already prevented, but users have just moved to making text links instead. I recognise that I'm never going to be able to stop the most determined linker (the example [dot] c0m) but would like to stop the casual example.com

Comment: Another option (depending upon your primary user base and their level of activity and cooperation) is a flag/vote down button, which can either get a moderator's attention, or hide/delete the comment after so many votes( or both! - though this might take more effort to implement, obviously)

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to do the trick:

```
!\b(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-z].)[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-z0-9\.\,\;\?\\'\\\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*\b!i
```

It is a slight modification of [this regex from Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=622).

I realize it’s a bit overwhelming, but that's to be expected when searching for URLs. Nevertheless, it matches everything on your list.

Alternatively, you could loop through each word in the description and use `parse_url()` to see how the word breaks down. I’ll leave the criteria for determining if it's a url to you. There’s still the potential for false positives, but they could be greatly reduced. Combined with Andrew’s idea of flagging questionable content for moderation, it could be a workable solution.

Comment: @Code Jockey: add it to the piped list `(com|edu|gov|...|ca|uk|travel)`

Comment: This also doesn't filter out a lot of the URL shorteners out there (bit.ly, goo.gl, etc...)

Comment: I have yet to find the _perfect_ regex for matching urls. I'd be interested in seeing it if anyone has.

Comment: such an expression would test the limits of a Cray supercomputer, but I'm sure it's _technically_ possible - I'm just picking nits!

Comment: I can live without the URL shorteners. I'm just trying to stop the blatant piss taking. For example we have had stuff like; "Don't buy here, save money and come direct to our store www.douchebags.com"

Comment: @Alex: I just came across this [PHP Bayesian Spam Filter](http://archive.atomicmpc.com.au/forums.asp?s=2&c=10&t=4466). I don't know anything about it... _yet_, but it may be worth looking into. See also [Class: Bayesian Spam Filter](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4236-PHP-Detect-spam-in-text-using-Bayesian-techniques.html)

Comment: It may be sufficient to test for dots that appear at the start or in the middle of words. (i.e. not a period.) `\.\b` Since you want to search through a _description_, I can't think of any reason a period would be in any other position than the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a regex to find the URLs, then specify what to replace them with using PHP's function [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace).

http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

**Edit:** Since this is user submitted data, you might want to do some validation before you store the "description" field, and check to see if it contains a URL. If it does, you can prevent the user from saving the form.

For this, you can use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), while still using a regex to find a URL.