# How to extract Twitter post photo from user RSS using PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, rss

I have simple Zend PHP application that will only fetch public posts from given channel using it's RSS link. I dont want to use OAuth method to save time. But the question is: can I substrack somehow the post image?

Or will have to use OAuth? If Yes, will everyone have to authorize just to read public posts?

This is simple RSS item:

```
<item>
<title>brdesign: A jak w RSSie si&#281; wy&#347;wietlaj&#261; foty? http://t.co/yzaKIdj9</title>
<description>brdesign: A jak w RSSie si&#281; wy&#347;wietlaj&#261; foty? http://t.co/yzaKIdj9</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Feb 2012 16:33:49 +0000</pubDate>
<guid>http://twitter.com/brdesign/statuses/168734555732312064</guid>
<link>http://twitter.com/brdesign/statuses/168734555732312064</link>
<twitter:source>web</twitter:source>
<twitter:place/>
</item>
```

Where photo is http://t.co/yzaKIdj9

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data response you can use the advise offered here to extract the URL from the string.

[Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

Comment: Yes, but the link forwards to another webpage not raw image (and i need raw image to display it in <img> tag).

Comment: You need to use the twitter api to get the raw image url.