# How to embed twitter tweets .. How to catch images from tweets URLs and display the actual images?

Tags: php, twitter, embedly

I was wondering what kind of method I could use to directly embed videos or pictures contained in twitter tweets directly ... For example .. below is a tweet from OBAMA

```
President Obama: "Right now, we have a real chance to reduce gun violence in America." http://t.co/tmCoUsPyyB #TimeToAct
```

The link that starts with htttp:// could be a picture .. How can I actually program it so that tweets are directly displayed with the images from the urls ?   I know PHP and I used the twitter API before , but I dont know how I could easily achieve that . Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The first step would to to pull the URLs of of the block of text, there is another question that points you how to solve this: [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

You can then use Embedly or a service like it to pull the metadata associated with that url. Here is an example of the meta data that Embedly will return: http://embed.ly/docs/explore/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FtmCoUsPyyB

The `html` attribute is what you want to render on your page.

We also have a PHP library you can use as well.

Hope that helps!